# Is there a token which neither can be redefined to be \outer nor can be affected by \uppercase/\lowercase?

Tags: tex-core, token

This is more an "academical" question:

Is there a token which neither can be redefined to be `\outer` nor can be affected by `\uppercase`/`\lowercase` no matter what `\lccode`s/`\uccode`s are current?

Assuming that functionality of the `\outer`-primitive is available/does not get disabled.

Comment: `\let\outer\relax` should solve the problem ;-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik No. ;-)  I want some tokens to be `\outer` in my code.  ;-)   One token not to be refedinable in terms of `\outer` and not affectable by `\uppercase`/`\lowercase` would be nice, e.g., with macros that insert sentinel-tokens for list-processing. The sentinel-token should not be transformable to s.th. else. The sentinel should not be redefinable in terms of `\outer` as that would break its usage with (internal) macros where it is inserted automatically as a compoonent of arguments. It is rather an academical/moot question.

Comment: That was an (admittedly not very good) joke, but the extra explanation would be nice in the question, for context.  However I'm afraid the answer to your question is “no, there's none”.  `\(upp|low)ercase` change _all_ character tokens (regardless of catcode, and assuming they have a proper `\(u|l)ccode`), so you are looking for a non-character token, which are control sequence (or symbol) tokens, which are all redefinable.  (Discarding internal frozen TeX tokens, like `\endwrite`, that cannot be redefined, but can't be used in your code either).

Comment: Well, unless of course you consider the fact that `\outer` tokens can't appear in the argument to anything (including `\(upp|low)ercase`), so the answer to your question is “any already `\outer` token”.  This raises an error `\outer\def\x{y}
\lowercase{\outer\def\x{z}}
\show\x`, but still redefines `\x`...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik   Control-word-tokens/control-symbol-tokens defined in terms of `\outer` are (regardless error-messages when using them inside `\lowercase`/`\uppercase`) not affected by `\uppercase`/`\lowercase` but (without wrapping them into `\uppercase`/`\lowercase`) can be redefined in terms of `\outer`: `\outer\def\x{y}\outer\def\x{z}\bye` . The condition of not being redefinable in terms of `\outer` is not strictly fulfilled for outer-tokens. ;-)

Comment: @UlrichDiez That's why “still redefines `\x`”.  My remark was clinging on the fact there's an error, so anyone sensible would stop there and the redefinition would not happen ;-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik "`\outer` tokens can't appear in the argument to anything" Some more nitpicking: `\outer`-tokens can occur in arguments of macros if they are "hit" by `\noexpand` right before macro-expansion takes place: `\def\foo#1{#1}\outer\def\x{y}\expandafter\foo\expandafter{\noexpand\x}\bye`.

Comment: @UlrichDiez For some definition of “appear”, yes. When you do that, they are temporarily `\let` to `\relax`, so they aren't technically `\outer` anymore.

Answer (score 4):

A frozen `\relax` token more or less meets the description. As it is not a character token it is not affected by lowercase and it can not be redefined at all, any attempt would generate an error, or redefine the standard `\relax`

```
\edef\zz{\ifnum0=0\else\fi}\show\zz


%define \zzz delimited by a frozen relax
\expandafter\def\expandafter\zzz\expandafter#\expandafter1\zz
         {\def\arg{#1}\show\arg}




% calling \zzz  shows delimted argument is abc
\edef\tmp{\noexpand\zzz abc\zz}
\tmp


%using a normal \relax does not delimit the argument
\zzz abc \relax


\bye
```

Comment: @UlrichDiez yes, as I didn't say what the "attempt"  should be the outcome is vague, I could re-word to say "an error or redefining a standard relax"

Comment: @UlrichDiez I added the text anyway, I think error is the most likely outcome.

Comment: For completion, the inner \endtemplate token and all of the font tokens also satisfy the condition. Reference: [macros - Accessing TeX's internal tokens - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/609423/accessing-texs-internal-tokens/). The other frozen tokens listed in point 6 there may also satisfy, but they're only accessible in interactive session so no point.