# Double colon in prettyref label

Tags: macros, cross-referencing

The [`prettyref`](https://mirror.koddos.net/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/prettyref/prettyref.pdf) package works by inspecting labels of the form `\label{format:name}` and creating a reference based on just the `format:`. The documentation says:

> Do not use the character `:` anywhere
> within the label except to seperate[sic] format from name.

I sadly have a use case where a .tex file is generated automatically with three-part labels `\label{first:second:name}`. An MWE is below. The implementation of `prettyref` is remarkably simple, so I'm wondering whether it can be adjusted to tolerate three-part labels.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{prettyref}

\newrefformat{diag:cla}{Class Diagram \ref{#1}}
\newrefformat{diag:seq}{Sequence Diagram \ref{#1}}

\begin{document}
Behold: \prettyref{diag:seq:FirstExportedDiagram}.

\begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{sequencediagram1.pdf}
    \caption{The first sequence diagram.}
    \label{diag:seq:FirstExportedDiagram}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:** I should add for completeness that I *also* still want to retain the ability to use old single-colon labels. The automatically exported .tex file actually has both (e.g. `\label{datatype:integer}`, which would be formatted with `\newrefformat{datatype}{\textit{\ref{#1}}}`, for example). Not saying the current answers don't comport with this, but it's good for future readers to know.

I should also mention that as the writer, I rely heavily on autocompletion to use these exported labels (there are a lot of them, and they are long). Something to keep in mind for certain format hacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [manual of the package prettyref](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/prettyref/prettyref.pdf) says:

> 11 `\def\prettyref#1{\@prettyref#1:}`
>
> `\@prettyref` The internal macro `\@prettyref` does all the work. It takes two arguements delimited by `:`. The first arguement is the format name. If the format has not been defined, a warning is issued and `\ref` is used. Otherwise, the reference is formatted. `\@prettyref` uses the LaTeX macros `\ref` and `\pageref` to access the `\newlabel` data structure. Hopefully this makes the package robust enough to use with various other pacakges.
>
> 12 `\def\@prettyref#1:#2:{%`
> 13   `\expandafter\ifx\csname pr@#1\endcsname\relax%`
> 14     `\PackageWarning{prettyref}{Reference format #1\space undefined}%`
> 15     `\ref{#1:#2}%`
> 16   `\else%`
> 17     `\csname pr@#1\endcsname{#1:#2}%`
> 18   `\fi%`
> 19 `}`

So `\prettyref` internally uses two `:`-delimited arguments for splitting that part of the argument that denotes the formatting.
LaTeX strips off curly braces surrounding an entire argument.
It also does so with delimited arguments.
Thus curly braces surrounding an entire delimited argument can be used for hiding instances of a delimiter occurring inside the delimited argument so that TeX's mechanism for grabbing the delimited argument won't be applied to these instances of the delimiter.

This implies:
Instead of `\prettyref{Formatting:RemainderOfLabelName}` you can do
`\prettyref{{Formatting}:RemainderOfLabelName}` or
`\prettyref{Formatting:{RemainderOfLabelName}}` or
`\prettyref{{Formatting}:{RemainderOfLabelName}}`.

Thus in your case for hiding `:` from TeX's mechanism for grabbing `:`-delimited arguments/for having things working out, just wrap that entire part of `\prettyref`'s argument into curly braces that denotes the formatting, i.e., instead of
`\prettyref{diag:seq:FirstExportedDiagram}`
do
`\prettyref{{diag:seq}:FirstExportedDiagram}`
or
`\prettyref{{diag:seq}:{FirstExportedDiagram}}`.

The MWE

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{prettyref}

\newrefformat{diag:cla}{Class Diagram \ref{#1}}
\newrefformat{diag:seq}{Sequence Diagram \ref{#1}}

\begin{document}
Behold: \prettyref{{diag:seq}:FirstExportedDiagram}.

\begin{figure}[h]
    %\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{sequencediagram1.pdf}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image.pdf}
    \caption{The first sequence diagram.}
    \label{diag:seq:FirstExportedDiagram}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

yields:

[image]

Explanation:

`\prettyref{{diag:seq}:FirstExportedDiagram}` yields:
`\@prettyref{diag:seq}:FirstExportedDiagram:`, which in turn yields:

```latex
  \expandafter\ifx\csname pr@diag:seq\endcsname\relax
    \PackageWarning{prettyref}{Reference format diag:seq\space undefined}%`
    \ref{diag:seq:FirstExportedDiagram}%`
  \else
    \csname pr@diag:seq\endcsname{diag:seq:FirstExportedDiagram}%`
  \fi
```

So it seems you actually don't need to redefine anything. With `\prettyref`'s argument just use additional curly braces here and there for hiding instances of `:` from TeX's mechanism for grabbing `:`-delimited arguments.

---

---

If you don't want to insert curly braces into your auto-generated code manually, and the presence of more than one colon not nested in curly braces always means that only/exactly the first two `:`-separated components represent the formatting specification, then you can do something like this which splits at colons not nested in curly braces and which does not remove/strip curly braces:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{prettyref}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
\newcommand\UD@firstofone[1]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%=============================================================================
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Extract first inner undelimited argument:
%%
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstArg{ABCDE} yields  {A}
%%
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstArg{{AB}CDE} yields  {AB}
%%
%% Due to \romannumeral-expansion the result is delivered after two 
%% expansion-steps/after "hitting" \UD@ExtractFirstArg with \expandafter
%% twice.
%%
%% \UD@ExtractFirstArg's argument must not be blank.
%% This case can be cranked out via \UD@CheckWhetherBlank before calling
%% \UD@ExtractFirstArg.
%%
%% Use frozen-\relax as delimiter for speeding things up.
%% I chose frozen-\relax because David Carlisle pointed out in
%% <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578877>
%% that frozen-\relax cannot be (re)defined in terms of \outer and cannot be
%% affected by \uppercase/\lowercase.
%%
%% \UD@ExtractFirstArg's argument may contain frozen-\relax:
%% The only effect is that internally more iterations are needed for
%% obtaining the result.
%%
%%.............................................................................
\@ifdefinable\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@Exchange
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\ifnum0=0\fi}%
  {\long\def\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax#1#2}{{#1}}%
}%
\expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter
  \UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\romannumeral
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@Exchange
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\ifnum0=0\fi}{\UD@stopromannumeral#1}%
  }{%
    \UD@stopromannumeral\romannumeral\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop
  }%
}{%
  \newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArg[1]%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  {\UD@stopromannumeral#1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax#1}}%
}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@GobbleToColon{\long\def\UD@GobbleToColon#1:{}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@KeepToColon{\long\def\UD@KeepToColon#1:{{#1}}}%
\newcommand\UD@SplitColon[4]{%
  % #1 Tokens to prepend to {<Already splitted stuff>{<stuff splitted in this iteration>}}{<New remainder to split>}
  %    if <Remainder to split> does contain colon.
  % #2 Tokens to prepend to <Already splitted stuff>{<Remainder to split>} 
  %    if <Remainder to split> does not contain colon.
  % #3 Already splitted stuff.
  % #4 Remainder to split.
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@GobbleToColon#4:}%
  {#2#3{#4}}{%
    \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\UD@GobbleToColon#4}{%
      \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{%
        \romannumeral
        \expandafter\UD@Exchange\expandafter{%
          \romannumeral
          \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
          \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
          \UD@stopromannumeral
          \expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArg\expandafter{\UD@KeepToColon#4}%
        }{\UD@stopromannumeral#3}%
      }{#1}%
    }%
  }%
}%
\renewcommand\prettyref[1]{%
  \UD@SplitColon{%
    \UD@SplitColon{% Here you could nest more \UD@SplitColon.
      \expandafter\UD@prettyref@morethanonecolon\UD@firstofone
    }{%
      \UD@prettyref@onecolon
    }%
  }{%
    \PackageWarning{prettyref}{No referencing format specified}\ref
  }{}{#1}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@prettyref@onecolon[2]{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname pr@#1\endcsname\relax
    \PackageWarning{prettyref}{Reference format #1\space undefined}%
    \ref{#1:#2}%
  \else
    \csname pr@#1\endcsname{#1:#2}%
  \fi
}%
\newcommand\UD@prettyref@morethanonecolon[3]{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname pr@#1:#2\endcsname\relax
    \PackageWarning{prettyref}{Reference format #1:#2\space undefined}%
    \ref{#1:#2:#3}%
  \else
    \csname pr@#1:#2\endcsname{#1:#2:#3}%
  \fi
}%
\makeatother

% In order to create hyperlinks, you can use
%
% \hyperref[{<referencing label>}]{<textual phrase which shall be a hyperlink>}
%
% As components of <textual phrase which shall be a hyperlink> you can use starred
% referencing-commands \ref*/\pageref* which themselves don't produce hyperlinks.
% This avoids errors due to nesting hyperlinks within hyperlinks.

\newrefformat{diag}{\hyperref[{#1}]{Diagram \ref*{#1}}}
\newrefformat{diag:cla}{\hyperref[{#1}]{Class Diagram \ref*{#1}}}
\newrefformat{diag:seq}{\hyperref[{#1}]{Sequence Diagram \ref*{#1}}}

\newcounter{democounter}

\begin{document}

You should get: Sequence Diagram 1\par
You actually get: \prettyref{diag:seq:FirstExportedDiagram:x:Y}
\medskip

You should get:  Sequence Diagram 2\par
You actually get: \prettyref{diag:seq:FirstExportedDiagram}
\medskip

You should get: Class Diagram 3\par
You actually get: \prettyref{diag:cla:FirstExportedDiagram}
\medskip

You should get: Diagram 4\par
You actually get: \prettyref{diag:FirstExportedDiagram}
\medskip

% You should get: 5 plus a warning "No referencing format specified" \par
% You actually get: \prettyref{FirstExportedDiagram}
% \medskip

You should get: 5\par
You actually get: \ref{FirstExportedDiagram}.
\medskip


Here the democounter is stepped. It has the value \refstepcounter{democounter}\thedemocounter.
\label{diag:seq:FirstExportedDiagram:x:Y}%
\bigskip

Here the democounter is stepped. It has the value \refstepcounter{democounter}\thedemocounter.
\label{diag:seq:FirstExportedDiagram}%
\bigskip

Here the democounter is stepped. It has the value \refstepcounter{democounter}\thedemocounter.
\label{diag:cla:FirstExportedDiagram}%
\bigskip

Here the democounter is stepped. It has the value \refstepcounter{democounter}\thedemocounter.
\label{diag:FirstExportedDiagram}%
\bigskip

Here the democounter is stepped. It has the value \refstepcounter{democounter}\thedemocounter.
\label{FirstExportedDiagram}%
\bigskip

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a clever solution, and produces the correct result versus Ulrike's answer. However, it is slightly tedious putting curly braces around part of an autocompleted label, so I'll wait out further answers.

Comment: @Mew I just added another example to my answer - does that code do what you need?

Comment: That works. I have accepted your answer. Two small notes that you could maybe help out with: 1. Overleaf's syntax highlighter warns that starting at `RemoveTillFrozenrelax`, and also starting at the first `}{%`, there is an unclosed group. The compiler doesn't find the unbalance, and I don't either. 2. Is there a way to hyperlink the entire string inserted by `\newrefformat` (autoref-style), instead of just the `\ref` part?

Comment: @Mew  Ad 1: I seldom use the web-interface/frontend Overleaf. The code checker of that frontend is not very good. I always turn it of by clicking "Menu" in the top-left-corner of the browser-window where Overleaf is displayed. Then a context-menu opens up where you can adjust what features and what TeX-platform (TeX Live 2014 - TeX Live 2021) and what TeX engine (LaTeX, i.e.,  dvi-mode; dvi will automatically be converted to pdf after compilation/pdfLaTeX/LuaLaTeX/XeLaTeX) you wish to use. There I toggle "Code check" to "Off". I like about Overleaf that it automatically detects knitR.

Comment: @Mew  Ad 2: I just edited the second example and modified the calls to `\newrefformat` so that hyperlinks are created. Hope this helps. ;-)

Comment: @Mew By the way - you should not have "accepted" until somebody posted a tricky expl3-solution. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It is not quite clear why prettyref delimits the end with a colon. The normal delimiter here is `\@nil`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{prettyref}

\newrefformat{diag:cla}{Class Diagram \ref{#1}}
\newrefformat{diag:seq}{Sequence Diagram \ref{#1}}
\makeatletter
\def\prettyref#1{\@prettyref#1\@nil}
\def\@prettyref#1:#2\@nil{%  
  \expandafter\ifx\csname pr@#1\endcsname\relax%
    \PackageWarning{prettyref}{Reference format #1\space undefined}%
    \ref{#1:#2}%
  \else%
    \csname pr@#1\endcsname{#1:#2}%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Behold: \prettyref{diag:seq:FirstExportedDiagram}.

\begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image.pdf}
    \caption{The first sequence diagram.}
    \label{diag:seq:FirstExportedDiagram}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code yields `Package prettyref Warning: Reference format diag undefined on input line 20.`. In the pdf-file you get `Behold: 1` instead of `Behold: Sequence Diagram 1`. That's because the formatting-component still is obtained by splitting at the first `:`. Delimited arguments can be wrapped into curly braces, however... ;-)

Comment: @UlrichDiez you can define a new format for a prefix with `\newrefformat{diag}{Diagram \ref{#1}}`, and I assumed that the OP wants to get the diag format for the three part label.

Comment: Surely it is a three-part-label, parts being divided from each other by `:`. But it seems the OP wants parts to be combined for denoting  the formatting-information. That's why in the question it is `\newrefformat{diag:seq}{Sequence Diagram...}` and not `\newrefformat{diag}{...}`. There are "sub-types" of `diag`. |||  Still your example, compiled as is, yields the warning about the formatting not being defined.

Comment: ah you are right, I overlooked that. In that case your bracing is probably the best. The alternative would be to split in three parts and then test if the last is empty.

Comment: I thought about splitting in the way suggested by you, too. But the next question in this matter will about having three `:` instead of two, then about four `:` instead of two... ;-)  I would not do this splittng at all. Instead I'd just define a `\prettyref`-command that has two undelimited arguments, one denoting the formatting, the other denoting the cross-referencing-label. ;-)