Macro to handle comma/semicolon separated list
I have a macro to handle to comma separated list that works.
\newcommand{\ndLDbl}[6]{\node[#5]#6(#1){#2};\node[]at([shift={(#4)}]#1){#3};}
\makeatletter\newcommand{\ndLDbL}[7]{%
 \def\dolist##1{\expandafter\@dolist##1,\@eol}%
 \def\@dolist##1,##2\@eol{\draw(##1)->(#1);\ifx\@eol##2\@eol\else%
     \@dolist##2\@eol\fi}
 \node[#5]#6(#1){#2};\node[]at([shift={(#4)}]#1){#3};%
 \ifx#7\empty\else\dolist{#7}\fi}\makeatother

An example usage:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\newcommand{\ndLDbl}[6]{%
  \node [#5] #6(#1) {#2};
  \node [] at ([shift={(#4)}]#1) {#3};
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ndLDbL}[7]{%
  \def\dolist##1{%
    \expandafter\@dolist##1,\@eol
  }%
  \def\@dolist##1,##2\@eol{%
    \draw (##1) -> (#1);
    \ifx\@eol##2\@eol
    \else
      \@dolist##2\@eol
    \fi
  }%
  \node [#5] #6 (#1) {#2};
  \node[] at ([shift={(#4)}]#1) {#3};
  \ifx#7\empty
  \else
    \dolist{#7}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    baseline={(0,0)},
    ->,
    >={Stealth[inset=4pt,length=12pt, angle'=40,round]},
    shorten >=1pt,
    auto,
    node distance=20mm,
    semithick,
    every state/.style={semithick,draw=black,text=black,minimum size=20},
  ]
  \ndLDbl{l01}{A}{2}{45:.7}{state}{}
  \ndLDbl{l02}{B}{3}{45:.7}{state}{at([shift={( 2,-0)}]l01)}

  \ndLDbL{l11}{C}{1}{75:.7}{state}{at([shift={(-0,-2)}]$(l01)!.5!(l02)$)}{l01,l02}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

I need a macro that can handle a similar list but separated by comma/semicolon (at random). How can that be done? I would like the comma for an arrowed arc and the semicolon for an arc without any arrow.

Can you please add an example of how you use this and of what you'd like to achieve?

please link to earlier posts. this is essentially a followup to at least one previous question. can you give an example of the input you want and the output you'd like it to produce? what do you mean by a list separated by commas (and? or?) semicolons at random?

you need arrows.meta. and calc.

do you have both separators in a single list or only one or the other? if the former, how is it determined where the list should be split first e.g. a,b;c,d;e;f. you said you wanted a comma to mean one thing and a semicolon another. but we have one more element than we have separators. and which is c, for example? or will you use a,b;c,d;e;f, so each element gets the immediately following separator?

How do you want this to behave in case the argument holding the list neither is empty nor contains comma nor contains semicolon? What is the purpose of \def\lis{,}%? What is the purpose of \ifx#7\empty? This might compare the meanings of the first two tokens of #7 or might compare the meaning of #7's only token to the meaning of \empty or, in case #7 is empty, compares the meaning of \empty to the meaning of subsequent \else. \@dolist does recursively call \@dolist inside \else...\fi which with long lists may lead to accumulating tokens \fi  and thus to blocking memory.

@UlrichDiez: As evident from the example, I link each node in the list to the current node. I want to link with a plain arc if followed by a semicolon and with an arrowed arc if followed by a comma. I have remove the redundant macro definition, which didn't work when placed as a parameter in the internal macro.

@cfr: The given example compiles for me. The separators will be mixed (a,b;c,d;e;f,) so each element gets the immediately following separator.

@DavidCarlisle: The test works for the code I have posted with pdflatex (I have picked up the test from one of the online examples).

@DavidCarlisle: the use of \empty is not the issue at the moment for me, though it might create a problem later; I shall try to see if I can get a error because of the way it's used. The issue is how to handle the list with mixed separators.

As evident from the example, I link each node in the list to the current node. I want to link with a plain arc if followed by a semicolon and with an arrowed arc if followed by a comma.
I just noticed that the code I had posted has been edited to correct missing bits ... thanks for that!

yes, it compiles because I added the missing bits :-).

Instead of \ifx#7\empty\else...\fi you might prefer \ifcat$\detokenize{#7}$\else...\fi.

Due to the 30000-character-limit for answers this answer needed to be split in two parts.
This is part 1 of the answer.
Part 1 of the answer holds general explanations of the workings of TeX and of the code/working example provided in part 2.
Part 2 of the answer holds the working example.

In that stage of TeX's processing of things (⁠expansion⁠) where macros and their arguments are processed⁠/​expanded⁠/​replaced by the tokens that form their replacement text, things are already tokenized and everything is either a control sequence token or an explicit character token.
(⁠Properties of explicit character tokens are character code and category.
The character code is the number which the codepoint of the character in question has in TeX's internal character encoding scheme. With traditional TeX engines TeX's internal character encoding scheme focuses on single byte encoding⁠/8 bit encoding and therefore provides 256 different codepoints, numbered from 0 to 255, whereof the codepoints 0 to 127 encode characters according to the American Standard Code for Information Interchange (⁠ASCII⁠). With LuaTeX- and XeTeX-based TeX engines the internal character encoding scheme is Unicode and when with these TeX engines it comes to writing to file⁠/​to reading from file, nowadays usually 8 bit Universal Coded Character Set Transformation Format (⁠UTF‑8⁠) is used⁠/​assumed for transforming the numbers of the codepoints provided by the Unicode standard into sequences of bytes that can be stored on⁠/​read from whatsoever data storage medium.
The category code assigned to a character occurring in the .tex input file denotes the purpose which that character has during the stage of tokenization when stuff is read from the .tex-input file and tokens are created and appended to TeX's token stream.
The category of a character token denotes the purpose which that token has in different stages of processing subsequent to tokenization.
For example the character \ usually has category code 0⁠(⁠escape⁠) and in the stage of tokenization causes TeX to start gathering from a line of the .tex input file characters that form the name of a control sequence token and when that gathering is done appending the corresponding control sequence token to the token stream.
For example the character $ usually has category code 3⁠(⁠math shift⁠) and therefore at the stage of tokenizing either—when in the .tex input file preceded by a backslash character \⁠/​by a character of category 0⁠(⁠escape⁠)—can be the name of a control symbol token \$—a control symbol token is a control sequence token whose name consists of a single character which is not of category 11⁠(⁠letter⁠)—or can be tokenized as an explicit character token $3 while in processing stages where typesetting takes places explicit character tokens of category 3⁠(⁠math shift⁠) like $3 cause TeX to enter or leave the typesetting mode for typesetting mathematical formulae.
For example A usually has category code 11⁠(⁠letter⁠) and therefore in the stage of tokenization either can be part of the name of a control word token—a control word token is a control sequence token whose name either consists of a single character of category 11⁠(⁠letter⁠) or consists of an amount of characters differing from 1—or can be tokenized as an explicit character token A11.  An explicit character token A11 in turn in the stage of writing to external text file denotes the instruction to write the character A. In stages of crating boxes for typesetting, an explicit character token A11 may denote the instruction to select a specific glyph from the current font which in that font represents the grapheme ⟨A⟩.)
So an argument of a macro can be considered a list of (⁠non-\outer⁠) tokens where explicit curly brace tokens (⁠{1⁠/​}2⁠) are balanced.
So the question is about processing an argument of a macro⁠/​a list of tokens, taking it for a list of items whereby the items consist of (⁠probably empty⁠) brace balanced lists of tokens and whereby items are separated one from another either by explicit comma character tokens of category 12⁠(⁠other⁠) ,12⁠, or by explicit semicolon character tokens of category 12⁠(⁠other⁠) ;12⁠.
In case a list of tokens consists only of a (⁠probably empty⁠) constellation of explicit space tokens (⁠␣10⁠)⁠, i⁠.⁠e⁠.⁠, explicit character tokens of category 10⁠(⁠space⁠) with character code 32 (⁠32 is the number of the codepoint of the space character in TeX's internal character encoding scheme which with traditional TeX engines is ASCII and with LuaTeX- and XeTeX-based TeX engines is Unicode⁠), that list of tokens is said to be blank.
Processing lists of items that are separated one from another by some separator in LaTeX usually is implemented by means of tail recursion. In the stage of expansion tail recursion often is done by means of a macro token which initiates an expansion cascade which at some stage initiates the next iteration by delivering the same macro token again, plus the arguments that in the next iteration are to be processed by that macro token. Processing lists of items by means of tail recursion often is done so that in each iteration the leftmost item of the remaining list is grabbed from the remaining list and processed and then the next iteration is done with that leftmost item and the tokens forming the delimiter at the right of that item removed from the remaining list, whereby iteration is terminated when the remaining list is empty or blank or when whatsoever other condition is met that makes further iteration obsolete.
This implies that you need routines for

grabbing⁠/​extracting the leftmost item from the (⁠remaining⁠) list and passing it as macro argument to routines for further examination and processing of the item and initiating the next iteration with the leftmost item removed from the list.
removing the leftmost item from the (⁠remaining⁠) list.
detecting whether conditions for terminating the loop are fulfilled and delivering tokens that are to be processed in these cases. Usually emptiness or blankness of the remaining list is a condition for terminating the tail-recursive loop.

Usually grabbing⁠/​extracting the leftmost item from the (⁠remaining⁠) list is implemented as follows:

Tokens are gathered from the left of the list until a token is found which forms a delimiter. Hereby it is ensured that no tokens (⁠explicit space tokens ␣10 preceding an undelimited argument and/or a pair of matching explicit curly brace tokens {1⁠/​}2 surrounding an entire delimited or undelimited argument⁠) are stripped off⁠/​removed in the course of grabbing macro arguments. You can do this by means of delimited macro arguments.
All explicit space tokens at the left and at the right of what has been gathered are removed⁠/​trimmed.
In case the remaining tokens after space token trimming can be considered a list of tokens that is nested between an outermost pair of matching explicit curly brace tokens (⁠{1⁠, }2⁠)⁠, that outermost pair of matching explicit curly brace tokens is stripped off.

In your scenario you also need routines for detecting whether the remaining list's next item is delimited by ,12 or is delimited by ;12 or whether the remaining list does not contain such a delimiter at all.
You can test whether the remaining list contains ,12 by appending ,12 to the remaining list and then removing the leftmost ,12‑delimited argument and its ,12‑delimiter from the remaining list and checking whether the remainder is empty. In case of emptiness the remaining list does not contain ,12⁠, otherwise it does contain ,12⁠.
In the same way you can test whether the remaining list contains ;12⁠.
So you can test whether the remaining list contains ,12⁠. If the remaining list contains ,12⁠, then extract the remaining list's first ,12‑delimited argument and check whether that contains ;12⁠. If the latter is the case also, the remaining list's next item is separated from the rest of the remaining list by ;12⁠. If the latter is not the case also, the remaining list's next item is separated from the rest of the remaining list by ,12⁠. If the remaining list does not contain ,12⁠, then check whether the remaining list contains ;12⁠. If the latter is the case also, the remaining list's next item is separated from the rest of the remaining list by ;12⁠, otherwise the remaining list neither does contain ,12 nor does contain ;12⁠.
Assuming the argument is a list where list items are separated from each other by comma or by semicolon you do tail recursion for iterating on the argument, removing list items one by one, and with each list item fork nine cases:
Case 1: Item is preceded by comma; item is trailed by comma.
Case 2: Item is preceded by comma; item is trailed by semicolon.
Case 3: Item is preceded by comma; item neither is trailed by comma nor is trailed by semicolon.
Case 4: Item is preceded by semicolon; item is trailed by comma.
Case 5: Item is preceded by semicolon; item is trailed by semicolon.
Case 6: Item is preceded by semicolon; item neither is trailed by comma nor is trailed by semicolon.
Case 7: Item neither is preceded by comma nor is preceded by semicolon; item is trailed by comma.
Case 8: Item neither is preceded by comma nor is preceded by semicolon; item is trailed by semicolon.
Case 9: Item neither is preceded by comma nor is preceded by semicolon; item neither is trailed by comma nor is trailed by semicolon.
The example in part 2 of the answer provides a routine \dolist where you can specify two arguments for each of the nine cases for specifying tokens to prepend/append to the tokens forming the list item in that case. Thus you need to handle eighteen macro arguments for the cases, one argument for holding the (remaining) list and one argument for holding the tokens that form the result accumulated so far. That's why a routine for delivering the K-th of L undelimited macro arguments is delivered with the example also.
Syntax of \dolist is:
\dolist{%
  {⟨Tokens to prepend to list-item in case list-item is preceded by comma and is trailed by comma⟩}%
  {⟨Tokens to append to list-item in case list-item is preceded by comma and is trailed by comma⟩}%
  {⟨Tokens to prepend to list-item in case list-item is preceded by comma and is trailed by semicolon⟩}%
  {⟨Tokens to append to list-item in case list-item is preceded by comma and is trailed by semicolon⟩}%
  {⟨Tokens to prepend to list-item in case list-item is preceded by comma and neither is trailed by comma nor is trailed by semicolon⟩}%
  {⟨Tokens to append to list-item in case list-item is preceded by comma and neither is trailed by comma nor is trailed by semicolon⟩}%
  {⟨Tokens to prepend to list-item in case list-item is preceded by semicolon and is trailed by comma⟩}%
  {⟨Tokens to append to list-item in case list-item is preceded by semicolon and is trailed by comma⟩}%
  {⟨Tokens to prepend to list-item in case list-item is preceded by semicolon and is trailed by semicolon⟩}%
  {⟨Tokens to append to list-item in case list-item is preceded by semicolon and is trailed by semicolon⟩}%
  {⟨Tokens to prepend to list-item in case list-item is preceded by semicolon and neither is trailed by comma nor is trailed by semicolon⟩}%
  {⟨Tokens to append to list-item in case list-item is preceded by semicolon and neither is trailed by comma nor is trailed by semicolon⟩}%
  {⟨Tokens to prepend to list-item in case list-item neither is preceded by comma nor is preceded by semicolon and is trailed by comma⟩}%
  {⟨Tokens to append to list-item in case list-item neither is preceded by comma nor is preceded by semicolon and is trailed by comma⟩}%
  {⟨Tokens to prepend to list-item in case list-item neither is preceded by comma nor is preceded by semicolon and is trailed by semicolon⟩}%
  {⟨Tokens to append to list-item in case list-item neither is preceded by comma nor is preceded by semicolon and is trailed by semicolon⟩>}%
  {⟨Tokens to prepend to list-item in case list-item neither is preceded by comma nor is preceded by semicolon and neither is trailed by comma nor is trailed by semicolon⟩}%
  {⟨Tokens to append to list-item in case list-item neither is preceded by comma nor is preceded by semicolon and neither is trailed by comma nor is trailed by semicolon⟩}%
}%
{⟨comma- and/or semicolon-separated list⟩}
Due to \romannumeral-expansion the result of \dolist is generated within two expansion steps.
With each item of the comma- and/or semicolon-separated list surrounding explicit space tokens if present, are removed and one level of surrounding explicit curly brace tokens if present, is removed before prepending the ⟨Tokens to prepend to list-item in case list-item is...⟩ and appending the ⟨Tokens to append to list-item in case list-item is...⟩ to the list item.
The gist of the \romannumeral-expansion driven tail recursive routine is:
\UD@dolistloop by a macro argument generated in the previous iteration obtains information about the delimiter that precedes the next item of the list and tests whether the next item of the list is delimited by comma or by semicolon or whether the remaining list doesn't contain such a delimiter and uses this information for either using \UD@@dolist for creating the next iteration/the next call to \UD@dolistloop or using \UD@@@dolist for processing the last list element and terminating \romannumeral-expansion and delivering the result.
In case you wish to learn about \romannumeral-expansion and other expansion trickery, the answers to the question How can I know the number of expandafters when appending to a csname macro? might be of interest.

Due to the 30000-character-limit for answers this answer needed to be split in two parts.
This is part 1 of the answer.
Part 1 of the answer holds general explanations of the workings of TeX and of the code/working example provided in part 2.
Part 2 of the answer holds the working example.

Due to the 30000-character-limit for answers this answer needed to be split in two parts.
This is part 2 of the answer.
Part 1 of the answer holds general explanations of the workings of TeX and of the code/working example provided in part 2.
Part 2 of the answer holds the working example.

\errorcontextlines=10000
\makeatletter
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Paraphernalia:
%%.............................................................................
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is blank (empty or only spaces):
%%.............................................................................
%% -- Take advantage of the fact that TeX discards space tokens when
%%    "fetching" _un_delimited arguments: --
%% \UD@CheckWhetherBlank{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that
%%                        argument which is to be checked is blank>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked is not blank>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherBlank[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo#1{}{}}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Extract K-th inner undelimited argument:
%%
%% \UD@ExtractKthArg{<integer K>}%
%%                  {<tokens in case list of undelimited args doesn't have a k-th argumnent>}%
%%                  {<list of undelimited args>} %
%% 
%% In case there is no K-th argument in <list of indelimited args> : 
%%   Does deliver <tokens in case list of undelimited args doesn't have a k-th argumnent.
%% In case there is a K-th argument in <list of indelimited args> : 
%%   Does deliver that K-th argument with one level of braces removed.
%%
%% Examples:
%%
%%   \UD@ExtractKthArg{0}{not available}{ABCDE} yields: not available
%%
%%   \UD@ExtractKthArg{3}{not available}{ABCDE} yields:  C
%%
%%   \UD@ExtractKthArg{3}{not available}{AB{CD}E} yields:  CD
%%
%%   \UD@ExtractKthArg{4}{not available}{{001}{002}{003}{004}{005}} yields: 004
%%
%%   \UD@ExtractKthArg{6}{not available}{{001}{002}{003}} yields: not available 
%% 
%%.............................................................................
\newcommand\UD@ExtractKthArg[2]{%
  \romannumeral
  % #1: <integer number K>
  % #2: <action if there is no K-th argument>
  \expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgCheck
  \expandafter{\romannumeral\number\number#1 000}{#2}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractKthArgCheck[3]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{\UD@stopromannumeral#2}{% empty
    \expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{#2}{#3}%
  }%
}%
\begingroup
\def\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop#1{%
  \endgroup
  \newcommand\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop[3]{%
    \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull
    \expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo##3{}.}{\UD@stopromannumeral##2}{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherNull{##1}{%
        \UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop{##3#1}%
      }{%
        \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}##3}%
        {\expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}##1}{##2}}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
\expandafter\expandafter\ifnum0=0\fi}%
%% Usage of frozen-\relax as delimiter is for speeding things up by reducing the
%% amount of iterations needed. I chose frozen-\relax because David Carlisle 
%% pointed out in   <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578877>
%% that frozen-\relax cannot be (re)defined in terms of \outer and cannot be
%% affected by \uppercase/\lowercase.
%%
%% \UD@ExtractFirstArg's argument may contain frozen-\relax:
%% The only effect is that internally more iterations are needed for
%% obtaining the result.
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo#1{}}%
  {\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax#1}}%
}%
%% End of code for \UD@ExtractKthArg.
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Extract first inner delimited argument:
%%
%% With \long\def\UD@KeepToComma#1,{{\UD@firstoftwo#1}}
%%
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces{\UD@KeepToComma}{A,B,C,D,E}{<Tokens to prepend>} yields  <Tokens to prepend>{A}
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces{\UD@KeepToComma}{{AB},C,D,E}{<Tokens to prepend>} yields  <Tokens to prepend>{{AB}}
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces{\UD@KeepToComma}{AB,C,D,E}{<Tokens to prepend>} yields  <Tokens to prepend>{AB}
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces{\UD@KeepToComma}{ AB ,C,D,E}{<Tokens to prepend>} yields  <Tokens to prepend>{<space token>AB<space token>}
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces{\UD@KeepToComma}{AB ,C,D,E}{<Tokens to prepend>} yields  <Tokens to prepend>{AB<space token>}
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces{\UD@KeepToComma}{ AB,C,D,E}{<Tokens to prepend>} yields  <Tokens to prepend>{<space token>AB}
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces{\UD@KeepToComma}{{AB,AB},C,D,E}{<Tokens to prepend>} yields  <Tokens to prepend>{{AB,AB}}
%%
%% When you triggered \romannumeral-expansion, you can terminate
%% \romannumeral-expansion by having <Tokens to prepend> = \UD@stopromannumeral.
%%
%% \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces's argument must contain the delimiter
%% outside curly braces!!!!  This is not checked but needs to be checked by the
%% routine that might call \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces !
%%
%% Use frozen-\relax as delimiter for speeding things up.
%% I chose frozen-\relax because David Carlisle pointed out in
%% <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578877>
%% that frozen-\relax cannot be (re)defined in terms of \outer and cannot be
%% affected by \uppercase/\lowercase.
%%
%% \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces's argument may contain frozen-\relax:
%% The only effect is that internally more iterations are needed for
%% obtaining the result.
%%
%%.............................................................................
\@ifdefinable\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@Exchange
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\ifnum0=0\fi}%
  {\long\def\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax#1#2}{{#1}}%
}%
\expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter
  \UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\romannumeral
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@Exchange
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\ifnum0=0\fi}%
    {\UD@stopromannumeral\expandafter\expandafter#1{}{}#2{}}%
  }{%
    \UD@stopromannumeral
    \expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBracesLoop
    \expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter
  }%
}{%
  \newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces[2]%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBracesLoop[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  {\UD@Exchange{#1}}%
  {\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBracesLoop
   \expandafter{\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax#1}}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether brace-balanced argument's first token is an explicit
%% space-token:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpace{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
%%                                       which is to be checked> does have a
%%                                       leading explicit space-token>}%
%%                                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
%%                                       which is to be checked> does not have a
%%                                       a leading explicit space-token>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpace[1]{%
  \romannumeral\UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}%
  {%
    % Let's nest things into \UD@firstoftwo{...}{} to make sure they are nested in braces
    % and thus do not disturb when the test is carried out within \halign/\valign:
    \expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral
      \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo
      \string{\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpaceB.#1 }{}%
    }{}%
  }%
}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpaceB{%
  \long\def\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpaceB#1 {%
    \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
    {\UD@Exchange{\UD@firstoftwo}}{\UD@Exchange{\UD@secondoftwo}}%
    {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}%
     \expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\string}%
  }%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Remove all surrounding spaces and one level of braces from argument 
%%
%% \UD@TrimAllLeadingspacesAndOneLevelOfBraces{<Argument>}{<Tokens to prepend>}
%% yields <Tokens to prepend>{<Argument with all surroundeing spaces and one level of braces removed>}
%%
%% When you triggered \romannumeral-expansion, you can terminate
%% \romannumeral-expansion by having <Tokens to prepend> = \UD@stopromannumeral.
%%.............................................................................
\newcommand\UD@NoSurroundBraces[2]{#1#2}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@GobbleToSpace{\long\def\UD@GobbleToSpace#1 {}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@KeepToSpace{\long\def\UD@KeepToSpace#1 {{\UD@firstoftwo#1}}}%
\newcommand\UD@TrimAllLeadingspacesAndOneLevelOfBraces[1]{%
   \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpace{#1}{%
     \expandafter\UD@TrimAllLeadingspacesAndOneLevelOfBraces\expandafter{\UD@GobbleToSpace#1}%
   }{\UD@TrimAllTrailingspacesLoop{#1 }{}{}}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@TrimAllTrailingspacesLoop[3]{%
   % #1 remaining list of space-delimited arguments
   % #2 Separator
   % #3 result gathered so far
   \UD@CheckWhetherBlank{#1}{%
     \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#3}{\UD@Exchange{{}}}{%
       \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@secondoftwo#3{}}{%
         \expandafter\UD@Exchange\expandafter{\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo#3{}}}%
       }{%
         \UD@Exchange{{#3}}%
       }%
     }%
   }{%
     \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{%
       \romannumeral
       \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces{\UD@KeepToSpace}{#1}{\UD@NoSurroundBraces{\UD@stopromannumeral#3#2}}%
     }{%
       \expandafter\UD@TrimAllTrailingspacesLoop\expandafter{\UD@GobbleToSpace#1}{ }%
     }%
   }%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\@ifdefinable\UD@gobbleToComma{\long\def\UD@gobbleToComma#1,{}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@gobbleToSemicolon{\long\def\UD@gobbleToSemicolon#1;{}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@KeepToComma{\long\def\UD@KeepToComma#1,{{\UD@firstoftwo#1}}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@KeepToSemicolon{\long\def\UD@KeepToSemicolon#1;{{\UD@firstoftwo#1}}}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\UD@firstofthree[3]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondofthree[3]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@thirdofthree[3]{#3}%
\newcommand\dolist[2]{\romannumeral\UD@dolistloop{#2}{}{\UD@firstofthree}{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@dolistloop[4]{%
  % #1 = remaining list to process
  % #2 = result accumulated so far
  % #3 = \UD@firstofthree - item neither is preceded by comma nor is preceded by semicolon
  %      \UD@secondofthree - item is preceded by comma
  %      \UD@thirdofthree - item is preceded by semicolon
  % #4 = tokens to prepend/append to item in the 9 cases
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@gobbleToComma#1,}{%
    \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@gobbleToSemicolon#1;}{%
      \UD@firstofthree % There is no trailing comma and no trailing semicolon
    }{%
      \UD@thirdofthree % There is a trailing semicolon
    }%
  }{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\UD@gobbleToSemicolon
      \romannumeral
      \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces{\UD@KeepToComma}{#1}{\UD@NoSurroundBraces\UD@stopromannumeral};%
    }{%
       \UD@secondofthree % There is a trailing comma
    }{%
       \UD@thirdofthree % There is a trailing semicolon
    }%
  }%
  {%
    % There is no trailing comma and no trailing semicolon
    #3{%item neither is preceded by comma nor is preceded by semicolon
      % Case 9: Item neither is preceded by comma nor is preceded by semicolon; item neither is trailed by comma nor is trailed by semicolon. 
      \UD@@@dolist{17}{18}%
    }{%item is preceded by comma
      % Case 3: Item is preceded by comma; item neither is trailed by comma nor is trailed by semicolon.  
      \UD@@@dolist{5}{6}%
    }{%item is preceded by semicolon
      % Case 6: Item is preceded by semicolon; item neither is trailed by comma nor is trailed by semicolon.  
      \UD@@@dolist{11}{12}%
    }%
  }{%
    % There is a trailing comma
    #3{%item neither is preceded by comma nor is preceded by semicolon
      % Case 7: Item neither is preceded by comma nor is preceded by semicolon; item is trailed by comma.
      \UD@@dolist{13}{14}%
    }{%item is preceded by comma
      % Case 1: Item is preceded by comma; item is trailed by comma.  
      \UD@@dolist{1}{2}%
    }{%item is preceded by semicolon
      % Case 4: Item is preceded by semicolon; item is trailed by comma.  
      \UD@@dolist{7}{8}%
    }%
    {\UD@KeepToComma}{\UD@gobbleToComma}{\UD@secondofthree}%
  }{%
    % There is a trailing semicolon
    #3{%item neither is preceded by comma nor is preceded by semicolon
      % Case 8: Item neither is preceded by comma nor is preceded by semicolon; item is trailed by semicolon.  
      \UD@@dolist{15}{16}%
    }{%item is preceded by comma
      % Case 2: Item is preceded by comma; item is trailed by semicolon.  
      \UD@@dolist{3}{4}%
    }{%item is preceded by semicolon
      % Case 5: Item is preceded by semicolon; item is trailed by semicolon.  
      \UD@@dolist{9}{10}%
    }%
    {\UD@KeepToSemicolon}{\UD@gobbleToSemicolon}{\UD@thirdofthree}%
  }%
  {#1}{#2}{#4}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@@dolist[8]{%
  % #1 = <prepend-arg no = 2*case-number - 1>
  % #2 = <append-arg no = 2*case-number>
  % #3 = \UD@KeepToComma/\UD@KeepToSemicolon
  % #4 = \UD@gobbleToComma/\UD@gobbleToSemicolon
  % #5 = <new preceded-by-flag>
  % #6 = \UD@dolistloop's #1 - <remaining list to process>
  % #7 = \UD@dolistloop's #2 - <result accumulated so far>
  % #8 = \UD@dolistloop's #4 - <tokens to prepend/append to item in the 9 cases>
  \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{%
    \romannumeral
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@Exchange\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
      \UD@ExtractKthArg{#2}{}{#8}%
    }{%
      \expandafter\UD@Exchange\expandafter{%
        \romannumeral\UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces{#3}{#6}{\UD@TrimAllLeadingspacesAndOneLevelOfBraces}{\UD@stopromannumeral}%
      }{%
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@Exchange\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
          \UD@ExtractKthArg{#1}{}{#8}%
        }{%
          \UD@stopromannumeral#7%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }{\expandafter\UD@dolistloop\expandafter{#4#6}}{#5}{#8}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@@@dolist[5]{%
  % #1 = <prepend-arg no = 2*case-number - 1>
  % #2 = <append-arg no = 2*case-number>
  % #3 = <remaining list to process>
  % #4 = <result accumulated so far>
  % #5 = <tokens to prepend/append to item in the 9 cases>
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@Exchange\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \UD@ExtractKthArg{#2}{}{#5}%
  }{%
    \expandafter\UD@Exchange\expandafter{%
      \romannumeral\UD@TrimAllLeadingspacesAndOneLevelOfBraces{#3}{\UD@stopromannumeral}%
    }{%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@Exchange\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
        \UD@ExtractKthArg{#1}{}{#5}%
      }{%
        \UD@stopromannumeral#4%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

%%=============================================================================

% Test-Suite, writes messages to console.

\message{%
  ^^J^^JList is: "(A),{(B)},{(C)};(D),{{(E)}}, F, ( G G ) , {(H)},{(I)} ; (J), {{(K)}}"^^J%
  \dolist{%
    {^^JStart of item preceded by comma and trailed by comma:}%
    {End of item preceded by comma and trailed by comma.}%
    {^^JStart of item preceded by comma and trailed by semicolon:}%
    {End of item preceded by comma and trailed by semicolon.}%
    {^^JStart of item preceded by comma and not trailed by comma or semicolon:}%
    {End of item preceded by comma and not trailed by comma or semicolon.}%
    {^^JStart of item preceded by semicolon and trailed by comma:}%
    {End of item preceded by semicolon and trailed by comma.}%
    {^^JStart of item preceded by semicolon and trailed by semicolon:}%
    {End of item preceded by semicolon and trailed by semicolon.}%
    {^^JStart of item preceded by semicolon and not trailed by comma or semicolon:}%
    {End of item preceded by semicolon and not trailed by comma or semicolon.}%
    {^^JStart of item not preceded by comma or semicolon and trailed by comma:}%
    {End of item not preceded by comma or semicolon and trailed by comma.}%
    {^^JStart of item not preceded by comma or semicolon and trailed by semicolon:}%
    {End of item not preceded by comma or semicolon and trailed by semicolon.}%
    {^^JStart of item neither preceded nor trailed by comma or semicolon:}%
    {End of item neither preceded nor trailed by comma or semicolon.}%
  }%
  {(A),{(B)},{(C)};(D),{{(E)}}, F, ( G G ) , {(H)},{(I)} ; (J), {{(K)}}}%
}%

\message{%
  ^^J^^JList is: " { (A) } "^^J%
  \dolist{%
    {^^JStart of item preceded by comma and trailed by comma:}%
    {End of item preceded by comma and trailed by comma.}%
    {^^JStart of item preceded by comma and trailed by semicolon:}%
    {End of item preceded by comma and trailed by semicolon.}%
    {^^JStart of item preceded by comma and not trailed by comma or semicolon:}%
    {End of item preceded by comma and not trailed by comma or semicolon.}%
    {^^JStart of item preceded by semicolon and trailed by comma:}%
    {End of item preceded by semicolon and trailed by comma.}%
    {^^JStart of item preceded by semicolon and trailed by semicolon:}%
    {End of item preceded by semicolon and trailed by semicolon.}%
    {^^JStart of item preceded by semicolon and not trailed by comma or semicolon:}%
    {End of item preceded by semicolon and not trailed by comma or semicolon.}%
    {^^JStart of item not preceded by comma or semicolon and trailed by comma:}%
    {End of item not preceded by comma or semicolon and trailed by comma.}%
    {^^JStart of item not preceded by comma or semicolon and trailed by semicolon:}%
    {End of item not preceded by comma or semicolon and trailed by semicolon.}%
    {^^JStart of item neither preceded nor trailed by comma or semicolon:}%
    {End of item neither preceded nor trailed by comma or semicolon.}%
  }%
  { { (A) } }%
}%

\stop

Output written to console:
pdflatex test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>


List is: "(A),{(B)},{(C)};(D),{{(E)}}, F, ( G G ) , {(H)},{(I)} ; (J), {{(K)}}"


Start of item not preceded by comma or semicolon and trailed by comma:{(A)}End 
of item not preceded by comma or semicolon and trailed by comma.
Start of item preceded by comma and trailed by comma:{(B)}End of item preceded 
by comma and trailed by comma.
Start of item preceded by comma and trailed by semicolon:{(C)}End of item prece
ded by comma and trailed by semicolon.
Start of item preceded by semicolon and trailed by comma:{(D)}End of item prece
ded by semicolon and trailed by comma.
Start of item preceded by comma and trailed by comma:{{(E)}}End of item precede
d by comma and trailed by comma.
Start of item preceded by comma and trailed by comma:{F}End of item preceded by
 comma and trailed by comma.
Start of item preceded by comma and trailed by comma:{( G G )}End of item prece
ded by comma and trailed by comma.
Start of item preceded by comma and trailed by comma:{(H)}End of item preceded 
by comma and trailed by comma.
Start of item preceded by comma and trailed by semicolon:{(I)}End of item prece
ded by comma and trailed by semicolon.
Start of item preceded by semicolon and trailed by comma:{(J)}End of item prece
ded by semicolon and trailed by comma.
Start of item preceded by comma and not trailed by comma or semicolon:{{(K)}}En
d of item preceded by comma and not trailed by comma or semicolon.


List is: " { (A) } "

Start of item neither preceded nor trailed by comma or semicolon:{ (A) }End of 
item neither preceded nor trailed by comma or semicolon. )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.


Due to the 30000-character-limit for answers this answer needed to be split in two parts.
This is part 2 of the answer.
Part 1 of the answer holds general explanations of the workings of TeX and of the code/working example provided in part 2.
Part 2 of the answer holds the working example.

Thanks, that was extensive. I shall take a long time to digest that. I might need your help for that.

@user209882 You are welcome. When you need help, don't hesitate to ask. I suggest  to ask questions here at TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange, referencing/quoting snippets of code where you need explanation. Asking here brings along the advantage of reaching a larger audience of experts who can show ways and tricks for achieving things and who can provide hints for optimizing the code I wrote. Besides this, it's good to have the community here as a corrective if necessary.
