Storing multiple arrays of strings in a command
I have modified the answer in Storing an array of strings in a command in order to allow multiple \storedata\mydata commands. That's the MWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newcount\tmpnum\tmpnum=0
\def\storedata#1#2{\edef\tmp{\string#1}\storedataA#2\end}
\def\storedataA#1{
   \ifx\end#1\else
      \advance\tmpnum by1
      \expandafter\def\csname data:\tmp:\the\tmpnum\endcsname{#1}%
      \expandafter\storedataA\fi
}
\def\getdata[#1]#2{\csname data:\string#2:#1\endcsname}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}
\storedata\mydata{{A}{B}{C}}
\storedata\mydata{{D}}
\storedata\myotherdata{{E}{F}{G}}

\foreach \n in {1,...,7}{%
\noindent mydata\n:\ \if\relax\getdata[\n]\mydata\relax EMPTY\else \getdata[\n]\mydata\fi \
myotherdata\n:\ \if\relax\getdata[\n]\myotherdata\relax EMPTY\else \getdata[\n]\myotherdata\fi\\
}
\end{document}


However, when I declare another array \myotherdata, it continues the counting of the previous declared data structure.
How do I fix this?

Welcome. // I suggest to study the expl3 solutions made more thoroughly. Have a look here https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/expl3/info .

there's a string of recent posts about this, most answered by egreg. the updated answer in expl3 to the question you linked has a bunch of very recent followups. basically about implementing arrays in expl3. that will be much easier in the end than doing it all at the tex level.

the problem with your code is that you are using a single count for all the arrays, whereas you would have to create a separate count for each new array you could obviously do it programmatically, but the thing about expl3 is it is already done for you ;).

As was suggested in comments, this is not the best approach. Arrays are much more easily implemented --- or, at least, facsimiles of arrays --- in expl3 and the commands thus created will be considerably more robust and more likely to provide useful error messages and logging.
However, since you provided a non-expl3 example selected from a question with a recently updated expl3 answer by egreg, nothing I could do in expl3 would have any point. So here's a way to fix the code you have.
The problem is you are using a single count register for all the arrays you create. Naturally, a single count can hold only a single value, so all your 'arrays' end up using that value. To do it this way, you need to understand the limitations of the code you're using. There are no arrays in TeX. We can construct the appearance of arrays for some purposes, but the functionality is not out-of-the-box.
So, if we want n arrays, we have to assign n count registers. Then each 'array' is created by using macros. The indexing is a side-effect of the naming. As far as TeX is concerned, the elements of each array are unrelated to one another.
Since we don't know how large n is, we need to create the counts on the fly. We can use the same \tmp for this which is used to create unique macro names for the 'elements'.
\def\storedataA#1{%

We test whether the count exists first. If it does, we don't do anything.
  \ifcsname tmpnum\tmp\endcsname\relax
  \else

Otherwise, we assign a new count register.
    \expandafter\newcount\csname tmpnum\tmp\endcsname
  \fi

Now we just need to adjust what follows.
  \ifx\end#1\else

First, we need to step the counter we just created rather than \tmpnum.
    \expandafter\advance\csname tmpnum\tmp\endcsname by1

To reduce the tangled knots of \expandafters, we pre-expand the value and just store it in a macro. This is fine for this bit because we're just using it to construct the name of the macro, so we don't need it to be treated as a number at all.
    \edef\tempa{\expandafter\the\csname tmpnum\tmp\endcsname}%

Then we plug this into the name of the macro which is defined to expand to the element.
    \expandafter\def\csname data:\tmp:\tempa\endcsname{#1}%

And finish as before
  \expandafter\storedataA\fi
}

Complete code:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\def\storedata#1#2{%
  \edef\tmp{\string#1}\storedataA#2\end
}
\def\storedataA#1{%
  \ifcsname tmpnum\tmp\endcsname\relax
  \else
    \expandafter\newcount\csname tmpnum\tmp\endcsname
  \fi
  \ifx\end#1\else
    \expandafter\advance\csname tmpnum\tmp\endcsname by1
    \edef\tempa{\expandafter\the\csname tmpnum\tmp\endcsname}%
    \expandafter\def\csname data:\tmp:\tempa\endcsname{#1}%
  \expandafter\storedataA\fi
}
\def\getdata[#1]#2{\csname data:\string#2:#1\endcsname}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}
\storedata\mydata{{A}{B}{C}}
\storedata\mydata{{D}}
\storedata\myotherdata{{E}{F}{G}}

\foreach \n in {1,...,7}{%
  \noindent mydata\n:\ \if\relax\getdata[\n]\mydata\relax EMPTY\else \getdata[\n]\mydata\fi \
  myotherdata\n:\ \if\relax\getdata[\n]\myotherdata\relax EMPTY\else \getdata[\n]\myotherdata\fi\\
}
\end{document}


expl3 sequences would be much nicer, though. then we could just say \seq_new:c { g_eder_#1_seq } and just define some wrappers for functions other people have written.

Excellent answer! Thank you!


In LaTeX it is common to have optional arguments nested in square brackets, but with your code the macro \getdata has a mandatory/non-optional argument in square brackets.
Instead of storing each array element in a macro on its own you can store the entire array in a macro and at the time of retrieving the data apply an expandable routine \UD@ExtractKthArg. This way you don't need \count-registers at all but can do with \romannumeral and \romannumeral-expansion.
A disadvantage of this approach is that changing the value of a single array element is more cumbersome and may consume more memory as the macro that needs to be redefined holds all values of the entire array, not just a single value of the array.

\makeatletter
%%
%% Code for \UD@ExtractKthArg
%%
%%=============================================================================
%% Paraphernalia:
%%    \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo, \UD@PassFirstToSecond, \UD@Exchange,
%%    \UD@stopromannumeral, \UD@CheckWhetherNull
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Extract K-th inner undelimited argument:
%%
%% \UD@ExtractKthArg{<TeX <number> quantity denoting integer value K>}%
%%                  {<tokens in case list of undelimited args doesn't have a K-th argumnent>}%
%%                  {<list of undelimited args>} %
%% 
%% In case there is no K-th argument in <list of indelimited args> : 
%%   Does deliver <tokens in case list of undelimited args doesn't have a K-th argumnent.
%% In case there is a K-th argument in <list of indelimited args> : 
%%   Does deliver that K-th argument with one level of braces removed.
%%
%% Examples:
%%
%%   \UD@ExtractKthArg{0}{not available}{ABCDE} yields: not available
%%
%%   \UD@ExtractKthArg{3}{not available}{ABCDE} yields:  C
%%
%%   \UD@ExtractKthArg{3}{not available}{AB{CD}E} yields:  CD
%%
%%   \UD@ExtractKthArg{4}{not available}{{001}{002}{003}{004}{005}} yields: 004
%%
%%   \UD@ExtractKthArg{6}{not available}{{001}{002}{003}} yields: not available 
%% 
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@ExtractKthArg[1]{%
  \romannumeral%
  % #1: <integer number K>
  \expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgCheck
  \expandafter{\romannumeral\number\number#1 000}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractKthArgCheck[3]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{\UD@stopromannumeral#2}{% empty
    \expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{#2}{#3}%
  }%
}%
\begingroup
\def\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop#1{%
  \endgroup
  \@ifdefinable\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax{%
    \long\def\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax##1##2#1{{##1}}%
  }%
  \newcommand\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop[3]{%
    \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo##3{}.}{\UD@stopromannumeral##2}{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherNull{##1}{%
        \UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop{##3#1}%
      }{%
        \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}##3}%
        {\expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}##1}{##2}}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
\expandafter\expandafter\ifnum0=0\fi}%
%% Usage of frozen-\relax as delimiter is for speeding things up by reducing the
%% amount of iterations needed. I chose frozen-\relax because David Carlisle 
%% pointed out in   <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578877>
%% that frozen-\relax cannot be (re)defined in terms of \outer and cannot be
%% affected by \uppercase/\lowercase.
%%
%% \UD@ExtractFirstArg's argument may contain frozen-\relax:
%% The only effect is that internally more iterations are needed for
%% obtaining the result.
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo#1{}}%
  {\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax#1}}%
}%
%%
%% End of code for \UD@ExtractKthArg.
%%
%% Code for \UD@CheckWhetherOnlyDefinedMacro / \UD@CheckWhetherOnlyUndefinedToken
%%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument's first token is an explicit character token 
%% of category 1 (begin group):
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherBrace{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked has a leading
%%                        explicit catcode-1-character-token>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked does not have a
%%                        leading explicit catcode-1-character-token>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherBrace[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{%
  \string#1.}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Check whether token is macro (only with macros the \meaning contains the
%% sequence ->) - the argument of \UD@CheckWhetherMacro must be a single token;
%% the argument of \UD@CheckWhetherMacro must not be empty:
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherMacro[1]{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \expandafter\UD@@CheckWhetherMacro\meaning#1->}%
  {\UD@secondoftwo}{\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@@CheckWhetherMacro{\long\def\UD@@CheckWhetherMacro#1->{}}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Check whether token is undefined control sequence (only with undefined 
%% control sequences the \meaning has the leading phrase "undefined"; besides
%% this \meaning never delivers no tokens at all) - the argument of 
%% \UD@CheckWhetherUndefined must be a single token; the argument of 
%% \UD@CheckWhetherUndefined must not be empty:
%%=============================================================================
\begingroup
\def\UD@CheckWhetherUndefined#1#2{%
  \endgroup
  \newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherUndefined[1]{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\UD@@CheckWhetherUndefined\meaning##1#1#2}%
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\UD@@CheckWhetherUndefined{%
    \def\UD@@CheckWhetherUndefined##1#1##2#2{##1}%
  }%
}%
\escapechar=-1\relax
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@Exchange
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
\expandafter\expandafter\ifnum0=0\fi}{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherUndefined\expandafter{\string\undefined}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Check whether the token list which forms the argument is a single non-space
%% token (as a single token it also isn't wrapped in braces):
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherSingleNonBlankNonBraced[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo#1{}{{}}}{%
    %#2 is blank
    \UD@secondoftwo
  }{%
    \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherBrace{#1}{%
        %#1 has a leading brace token
        \UD@secondoftwo
      }{%
        \UD@firstoftwo
      }%
    }{%
      %#1 is not a single undelimited argument but several undelimied arguments
      \UD@secondoftwo
    }%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherOnlyDefinedMacro[1]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherSingleNonBlankNonBraced{#1}{%
     \UD@CheckWhetherMacro{#1}{%
       \UD@firstoftwo
     }{%
       \UD@secondoftwo
     }%
  }{\UD@secondoftwo}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherOnlyUndefinedToken[1]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherSingleNonBlankNonBraced{#1}{%
     \UD@CheckWhetherUndefined{#1}{%
       \UD@firstoftwo
     }{%
       \UD@secondoftwo
     }%
  }{\UD@secondoftwo}%
}%
%%
%% End of code for \UD@CheckWhetherOnlyDefinedMacro / \UD@CheckWhetherOnlyUndefinedToken
%%
\makeatother

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\storedata[2]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherOnlyUndefinedToken{#1}{\def#1{#2}}{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherOnlyDefinedMacro{#1}{%
      % Here one should crank out whether #1 is a macro which processes arguments/parameter text,
      % but that is a "hard" task. Because by parsing the result of \meaning you cannot reliably
      % distinguish a <definition text>'s <parameter text> from the definition's <balanced text>.
      % \globaldefs having a non-positive value is assumed; the assignment is
      % restricted to the local scope.
      \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\the\toks@}{%
        \toks@\expandafter{#1#2}\edef#1{\the\toks@}\toks@
      }%
    }{%
      Error: \detokenize{#1} is neither undefined nor a macro%
    }%
  }%
}%
\@ifdefinable\getdata{%
  \long\def\getdata[#1]#2{%
    \romannumeral
    \UD@CheckWhetherOnlyDefinedMacro{#2}%
    {%
      % Here one should crank out whether #1 is a macro which processes arguments/parameter text,
      % but that is a "hard" task. Because by parsing the result of \meaning you cannot reliably
      % distinguish a <definition text>'s <parameter text> from the definition's <balanced text>.
      \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond
      \expandafter{#2}{%
        % \romannumeral is already running and driving expansion, so let's remove
        % the \romannumeral coming from \UD@ExtractKthArg.
        \expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\UD@ExtractKthArg{#1}{array element not available}%
      }%
    }%
    {\UD@stopromannumeral Error: \detokenize{#2} is not a defined macro}%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\storedata\mydata{{A}{B}{C}}
\storedata\mydata{{D}}
\storedata\myotherdata{{E}{F}{G}}

\foreach \n in {-1,...,7}{%
  \ifnum\n>-1 \bigskip\fi
  \par\noindent
  \texttt{\string\n}=\n\\
  \texttt{\string\getdata}[\n]\texttt{\string\mydata}: \getdata[\n]\mydata\\
  \texttt{\string\getdata}[\n]\texttt{\string\myotherdata}: \getdata[\n]\myotherdata
}

\end{document}


