Command to expand from an array
I want to create a command that can expand variables in an array as separate function parameters to another command.
\command1{1, 2, 3} -> \command2{1}{2}{3}

How to do this?

welcome! please always include a minimal working example (or non-working if needs be) showing what you've tried. I'm guessing you want to do this with the latex format but, in truth, I have no idea.

How to treat blank/empty comma-list items/surrounding spaces/surrounding curly braces {..}?  Do you want \commandA{1,2,3} and \commandA{ 1 , 2 , 3}  and \commandA{ 1, {2} ,, ,,,3, }  all to yield \commandB{1}{2}{3}?  Do you want this in LaTeX 2e? In plain TeX?

Assuming you want to do this with the LaTeX format, you can use the \SplitArgument argument processor with \NewDocumentCommand. For example,
\documentclass{article}
\NewDocumentCommand \ThendalCommand { >{\SplitArgument{2}{,}} m }
{%
  \ThendalCommandAux#1%
}
\NewDocumentCommand \ThendalCommandAux { mmm }
{%
  Do something with #1 and something else with #2 and something different again with #3.%
}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\ThendalCommand{aardvarks, antelopes, anteaters}

\ThendalCommand{{bananas, bushes or blackberries}, {honey dew, deadly nightshade and mulberry trees}, {holly and ivy, kisses and mistletoe, acorns and grand oak trees}}
\end{document}



First: you cannot use simply control sequences \command1 and \command2 as different control sequences in TeX. They are, in fact \command 1 and \command 2.
My example uses \command as a expandable macro which gets comma separated list and returns a list separated by brackets. It can be used in \edef, for example. So after \edef\list{\command{1, 2, 3}} is done the \list is macro which includes {1}{2}{3}. You can put such macro contents to \othercommand by \expandafter\othercommand\list.
For testing purpose I defined \othercommand as \message TeX primitive. This macro have to know where the list {1}{2}{3} ends, so it uses a parameter separated by semicolon.
\def\command#1{\commandA #1,\end,}
\def\commandA #1#2,{\ifx\end#1\else {#1#2}\expandafter\commandA\fi}

\def\othercommand #1;{\message{arguments are: #1}} % for testing

\edef\list{\command{1, 2, 3}}
\expandafter\othercommand\list;  % run test, must be separated by semicolon

\bye


Probably the answers to Easy way to convert \command{x}{y} to \command{x,y} are of interest to you.

With this answer

\stuff like \this denotes TeX-code that exists in .tex-input files, i.e., in text files.
\stuffl11i11k11e11␣10\this denotes tokens. Tokens come into being and exist while the TeX program is running. They come into being in a process called tokenization. Tokenization, in Knuth's analogy of TeX being a beast with eyes and digestive tract, takes place in TeX's mouth. The subscript with explicit character tokens denotes their category.


Under normal category code régime names of control word tokens should better not contain digits:
Digit characters under normal category code régime are assigned category 12(other) while at the time of tokenization only characters of category code 11(letter) are assumed to be components of names of control word tokens. Therefore under normal category code régime the code-snippet \command1 is not tokenized as a single control word token \command1 but is tokenized as two tokens \command112 and the code-snippet \command2 is not tokenized as a single control word token \command2 but is tokenized as two tokens \command212. Under normal category code régime control word tokens whose names contain digit characters cannot be produced at the time of tokenization, but can only be produced via expanding tokens \csname...\endcsname at the time of expansion. Expansion, in Knuth's analogy of TeX being a beast with eyes and digestive tract, is a "regurgitative process" which takes place in TeX's gullet.
Therefore with the example below \commandA is used instead of \command1 and \commandB is used instead of \command2.

If you like vintage LaTeX code, I can offer an expandable routine
\UD@PassCommaListAsUndelimitedList{1, 2 , {3}, ,, ,  4}{⟨tokens to prepend⟩}
→
⟨tokens to prepend⟩{1}{2}{3}{4}.
I.e., when constructing the list of delimited arguments,

blank items of the comma-list are ignored. ("Blank" in this context means that the item either does not have tokens at all or only consists of one or more explicit space tokens (␣10).)
explicit space tokens (␣10) leading/trailing/surrounding all other tokens of a non-blank item of the comma-list and one outermost level of surrounding braces, {1...}2, if present, are removed from non-blank items of the comma-list. The possibility of nesting the tokens belonging to an item of the comma-list between { and }  allows you to hide commas that shall not separate the comma-list's items but shall be part of an item of the comma-list. This also allows you to have items within the comma-list that have leading and/or trailing explicit space tokens that do not get stripped off.

There are a few more things to say:

Carrying out \UD@PassCommaListAsUndelimitedList works by expansion only. No scratch-assignments or the like, which would require processing things in TeX's stomach, are done. Therefore items of the comma-list containing (non-doubled) macro-parameter character-tokens #6, like in  #1 / #6112, does not disturb the course of the carrying out of the \UD@PassCommaListAsUndelimitedList-mechanism.
The expansion chain initiated by \UD@PassCommaListAsUndelimitedList does neither involve any \if/\else/\fi nor involve any \csname..\endcsname. Therefore the items of the comma-list containing unmatched \if/\else/\fi/\csname/\endcsname does not disturb the course of expansion. However, curly braces {..} are to be balanced with items of the comma-list—you cannot have an item within the comma-list wherein unmatched {1 or unmatched }2 occur.
While the expansion chain is done, tokens coming from macro-arguments that are provided by the user are always nested between {1...}2. Therefore the items of the comma-list containing &4 or \\ or the like does not intercept the course of expansion in case \UD@PassCommaListAsUndelimitedList is carried out inside a tabular-environment or inside an alignment.
The end of the list is not detected by encountering a terminating sentinel token but by detecting emptiness/blankness of arguments. Therefore no tokens but \outer-tokens are forbidden to occur in the comma-list. However, don't redefine macros that belong to the \UD@PassCommaListAsUndelimitedList-mechanism. ;-)

\romannumeral is used a lot with the example below . This might be surprising at first glimpse. So let's try to explain:
A peculiarity of \romannumeral is:
\romannumeral triggers expanding subsequent expandable tokens and gathering non-expandable tokens until an entire ⟨number⟩ is gathered. The tokens forming the ⟨number⟩ are removed from the token-stream. Only in case the ⟨number⟩ gathered is positive, tokens denoting lowercase roman representation of the value denoted by that ⟨number⟩ are prepended to the token-stream. In case the value of the ⟨number⟩ gathered is non-positive, no tokens are prepended to the token-stream. Expanding subsequent expandable tokens can be used for, in the course of gathering tokens belonging to the ⟨number⟩, having TeX flip macro arguments around and having TeX add tokens to the token-stream and having TeX remove tokens from the token-stream, i.e., for changing the order in which subsequent tokens occur in the token-stream.
Thus, in the following example \romannumeral/\romannumeral is not used for producing lowercase roman notation of numbers but is (ab?)used for having TeX itself trigger expansion steps until the token \UD@stopromannumeral is the first token in the token-stream and is taken for the ⟨number⟩ to gather. The control word token \UD@stopromannumeral denotes the value 0 in a way where TeX does seek neither for more digits nor for an optional space that might serve for separating tokens belonging to the ⟨number⟩ from the rest of the token-stream and that therefore might get removed. I.e., if, in the course of gathering a ⟨number⟩ for \romannumeral, TeX encounters the token \UD@stopromannumeral, then the process of gathering tokens for the ⟨number⟩ finishes. The value 0 denoted by the token \UD@stopromannumeral is not positive, so that, after removing the token \UD@stopromannumeral from the token-stream, no tokens are prepended to the token-stream.
(The result of expanding \romannumeral\UD@stopromannumeral is removing \romannumeral\UD@stopromannumeral from the token stream and delivering no token at all in return.)
%%\errorcontextlines=10000
\makeatletter
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Paraphernalia:
%%.............................................................................
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecondAndThird[3]{#2{#1}#3{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is blank (empty or only spaces):
%%.............................................................................
%% -- Take advantage of the fact that TeX discards space tokens when
%%    "fetching" _un_delimited arguments: --
%% \UD@CheckWhetherBlank{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that
%%                        argument which is to be checked is blank>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked is not blank>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherBlank[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo#1{}{}}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Extract first inner delimited argument:
%%
%% With \long\def\UD@KeepToComma#1,{{\UD@firstoftwo#1}}
%%
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces{\UD@KeepToComma}{A,B,C,D,E}{<Tokens to prepend>} yields  <Tokens to prepend>{A}
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces{\UD@KeepToComma}{{AB},C,D,E}{<Tokens to prepend>} yields  <Tokens to prepend>{{AB}}
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces{\UD@KeepToComma}{AB,C,D,E}{<Tokens to prepend>} yields  <Tokens to prepend>{AB}
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces{\UD@KeepToComma}{ AB ,C,D,E}{<Tokens to prepend>} yields  <Tokens to prepend>{<space token>AB<space token>}
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces{\UD@KeepToComma}{AB ,C,D,E}{<Tokens to prepend>} yields  <Tokens to prepend>{AB<space token>}
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces{\UD@KeepToComma}{ AB,C,D,E}{<Tokens to prepend>} yields  <Tokens to prepend>{<space token>AB}
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces{\UD@KeepToComma}{{AB,AB},C,D,E}{<Tokens to prepend>} yields  <Tokens to prepend>{{AB,AB}}
%%
%% When you triggered \romannumeral-expansion, you can terminate
%% \romannumeral-expansion by having <Tokens to prepend> = \UD@stopromannumeral...
%%
%% \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces's delimiter-separated-list-
%% argument must contain the delimiter outside curly braces!!!!  
%% This is not checked but needs to be checked by the
%% routine that might call \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces !
%%
%% Use frozen-\relax as delimiter for speeding things up.
%% I chose frozen-\relax because David Carlisle pointed out in
%% <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578877>
%% that frozen-\relax cannot be (re)defined in terms of \outer and cannot be
%% affected by \uppercase/\lowercase.
%%
%% \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces's delimiter-separated-list-
%% argument may contain frozen-\relax:
%% The only effect is that internally more iterations are needed for
%% obtaining the result.
%%
%%.............................................................................
\@ifdefinable\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@Exchange
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\ifnum0=0\fi}%
  {\long\def\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax#1#2}{{#1}}%
}%
\expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter
  \UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\romannumeral
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@Exchange
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\ifnum0=0\fi}%
    {\UD@stopromannumeral\expandafter\expandafter#1{}{}#2{}}%
  }{%
    \UD@stopromannumeral
    \expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBracesLoop
    \expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter
  }%
}{%
  \newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces[2]%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBracesLoop[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  {\UD@Exchange{#1}}%
  {\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBracesLoop
   \expandafter{\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax#1}}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Remove all surrounding spaces and one level of braces from argument 
%%
%% \UD@TrimAllLeadingspacesAndOneLevelOfBraces{<Argument>}{<Tokens to prepend>}
%% yields <Tokens to prepend>{<Argument with all surroundeing spaces and one level of braces removed>}
%%
%% When you triggered \romannumeral-expansion, you can terminate
%% \romannumeral-expansion by having <Tokens to prepend> = \UD@stopromannumeral...
%%.............................................................................
\newcommand\UD@NoSurroundBraces[2]{#1#2}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@GobbleToSpace{\long\def\UD@GobbleToSpace#1 {}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@KeepToSpace{\long\def\UD@KeepToSpace#1 {{\UD@firstoftwo#1}}}%
\newcommand\UD@TrimAllLeadingspacesAndOneLevelOfBraces[1]{%
  \UD@TrimAllSurroundingspacesLoop{#1 }{}{}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@TrimAllSurroundingspacesLoop[3]{%
  % #1 remaining list of space-delimited arguments
  % #2 Separator
  % #3 result gathered so far
  \UD@CheckWhetherBlank{#1}{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#3}{\UD@PassFirstToSecond{}}{%
      \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@secondoftwo#3{}}{%
        \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo#3{}}%
      }{%
        \UD@PassFirstToSecond{#3}%
      }%
    }%
  }{%
    \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecondAndThird\expandafter{%
      \romannumeral
      \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces{\UD@KeepToSpace}{#1}{\UD@NoSurroundBraces{\UD@stopromannumeral#3#2}}%
    }{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherNull
    }{%
      {\UD@PassFirstToSecond{}}{\UD@PassFirstToSecond{ }}%
      {\expandafter\UD@TrimAllSurroundingspacesLoop\expandafter{\UD@GobbleToSpace#1}}%
    }%
  }%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% \UD@PassCommaListAsUndelimitedList{<comma list>}{<Tokens to prepend>}
%%   \UD@PassCommaListAsUndelimitedList{1, 2 , {3}, 4}{<Tokens to prepend>}
%%   ->
%%   <Tokens to prepend>{1}{2}{3}{4}
%%
%% When you triggered \romannumeral-expansion, you can terminate
%% \romannumeral-expansion by having <Tokens to prepend> = \UD@stopromannumeral..
%%
%%.............................................................................
\@ifdefinable\UD@gobbleToComma{\long\def\UD@gobbleToComma#1,{}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@KeepToComma{\long\def\UD@KeepToComma#1,{{\UD@firstoftwo#1}}}%
%%.............................................................................
\newcommand\UD@PassCommaListAsUndelimitedList[1]{%
  \UD@PassCommaListAsUndelimitedListLoop{#1}{}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@PassCommaListAsUndelimitedListLoop[2]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@gobbleToComma#1,}{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherBlank{#1}{\UD@Exchange{#2}}{%
      \expandafter\UD@Exchange\expandafter{%
        \romannumeral
        \UD@TrimAllLeadingspacesAndOneLevelOfBraces{#1}{\UD@stopromannumeral#2}%
      }%
    }%
  }{%
    \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces{\UD@KeepToComma}{#1}{\UD@CheckWhetherBlank}{%
      \UD@PassFirstToSecond{#2}%
    }{%
      \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{%
        \romannumeral
        \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces{\UD@KeepToComma}%
                                              {#1}%
                                              {\UD@TrimAllLeadingspacesAndOneLevelOfBraces}%
                                              {\UD@stopromannumeral#2}%
      }%
    }%
    {\expandafter\UD@PassCommaListAsUndelimitedListLoop\expandafter{\UD@gobbleToComma#1}}%
  }%
}%
%\makeatother
%%=============================================================================

\message{^^J!\detokenize\expandafter{%
  \romannumeral
  \UD@PassCommaListAsUndelimitedList{A, B, {C}, , D ,{E} ,, , , ,}{\UD@stopromannumeral\macro}%
}!}%

\message{^^J!\detokenize\expandafter{%
  \romannumeral
  \UD@PassCommaListAsUndelimitedList{ {C}  }{\UD@stopromannumeral\macro}%
}!}%

\message{^^J!\detokenize\expandafter{%
  \romannumeral
  \UD@PassCommaListAsUndelimitedList{  }{\UD@stopromannumeral\macro}%
}!}%

\message{^^J!\detokenize\expandafter{%
  \romannumeral
  \UD@PassCommaListAsUndelimitedList{ {}  }{\UD@stopromannumeral\macro}%
}!}%

\message{^^J!\detokenize\expandafter{%
  \romannumeral
  \UD@PassCommaListAsUndelimitedList{ {} , }{\UD@stopromannumeral\macro}%
}!}%

\message{^^J!\detokenize\expandafter{%
  \romannumeral
  \UD@PassCommaListAsUndelimitedList{ , {}  }{\UD@stopromannumeral\macro}%
}!}%

\message{^^J!\detokenize\expandafter{%
  \romannumeral
  \UD@PassCommaListAsUndelimitedList{  ,  }{\UD@stopromannumeral\macro}%
}!}%

%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand\commandA[1]{%
  \UD@PassCommaListAsUndelimitedList{#1}{\commandB}%
}%

\makeatother

\newcommand\commandB{\string\commandB}%

\message{^^J%
  \commandA{1, 2, 3}%
}%

\stop

Console output
!\macro {A}{B}{C}{D}{E}! 
!\macro {C}! 
!\macro ! 
!\macro {}! 
!\macro {}! 
!\macro {}! 
!\macro ! 
\commandB{1}{2}{3}


If you like using expl3, the LaTeX3 programming layer, I can offer an expandable routine
\UDPassCommaListAsUndelimitedList{1, 2 , {3}, ,, ,  4}{⟨tokens to prepend⟩}
→
⟨tokens to prepend⟩{1}{2}{3}{4}.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Nn \__UDStuff_exp_not_braces:n {{\exp_not:n {#1}}}
\cs_new:Npn \UDPassCommaListAsUndelimitedList #1 #2 {
  \exp_args:Nne \use:nn {#2} { \clist_map_function:nN {#1} \__UDStuff_exp_not_braces:n }
}
%%.............................................................................
%% Message-handling when defining \UDstopromannumeral:
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_msg_module_type_prop { UDStuff } {}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_msg_module_name_prop { UDStuff } {Macro-Defined-In-Preamble:}
\msg_new:nnnn 
  {UDStuff}{Already Defined} 
  {
    Command\ #1\ already\ defined\ \msg_line_context: .
  }
  {
    Your\ command\ was\ ignored.\\
    Type\ I\ <command>\ <return>\ to\ replace\ it\ with\ another\ command,
    \ or\ <return>\ to\ continue\ without\ it.
  }
\cs_if_free:NTF \UDstopromannumeral {
  \tex_chardef:D \UDstopromannumeral=`\^^00~
}{
  \msg_error:nnx {UDStuff}{Already Defined}{\iow_char:N \\ \cs_to_str:N \UDstopromannumeral} 
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\message{^^J!\detokenize\expandafter{%
  \romannumeral
  \UDPassCommaListAsUndelimitedList{A, B, {C}, , D ,{E} ,, , , ,}{\UDstopromannumeral\macro}%
}!}%

\message{^^J!\detokenize\expandafter{%
  \romannumeral
  \UDPassCommaListAsUndelimitedList{ {C}  }{\UDstopromannumeral\macro}%
}!}%

\message{^^J!\detokenize\expandafter{%
  \romannumeral
  \UDPassCommaListAsUndelimitedList{  }{\UDstopromannumeral\macro}%
}!}%

\message{^^J!\detokenize\expandafter{%
  \romannumeral
  \UDPassCommaListAsUndelimitedList{ {}  }{\UDstopromannumeral\macro}%
}!}%

\message{^^J!\detokenize\expandafter{%
  \romannumeral
  \UDPassCommaListAsUndelimitedList{ {} , }{\UDstopromannumeral\macro}%
}!}%

\message{^^J!\detokenize\expandafter{%
  \romannumeral
  \UDPassCommaListAsUndelimitedList{ , {}  }{\UDstopromannumeral\macro}%
}!}%

\message{^^J!\detokenize\expandafter{%
  \romannumeral
  \UDPassCommaListAsUndelimitedList{  ,  }{\UDstopromannumeral\macro}%
}!}%

%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand\commandA[1]{%
  \UDPassCommaListAsUndelimitedList{#1}{\commandB}%
}%

\newcommand\commandB{\string\commandB}%

\message{^^J%
  \commandA{1, 2, 3}%
}%

\stop

