Trim spaces off end of a TeX command argument
I'm making some custom .sty packages I can reuse in my university projects, for stuff like exam relations and others. At the moment I'm trying to make a simple command with 2 arguments, that has to define a list of macros related to the value of argument #1.
For example, with a call like \command{arg1}{arg2} I would define a macro in the form of \@macro_arg1{arg2}. I already handled a simple argument parser, in which I can use arg2 in the form of a key-value list of arguments, so that my code would parse \makemacros{foo}{key1=val1,key2=val2} as 2 different macros \@key1_foo{val1} and \@key2_foo{val2}.
I then have a list of valid keys, that I can use inside my command, in order to make sure I'm building a predictable set of macros, so that I can make a generic \newcommand{\key1}[1]{\@key1_#1} without messing with undefined macros.
Basically, I should be able to write \makemacros{foo}{key1=val1,key2=val2}, it then creates 2 macros \@key1_foo{val1} and \@key2_foo{val2}, and I can print the value of those macros with the commands \key1{foo} or \key2{foo}, because I already know that key1 and key2 are valid keys, for which a command to print the relative macro value actually exists.
The problem I'm facing, though, is much more stupid than any of this: how the hell am I supposed to treat an argument with spaces?
I really think that a feature that allows me to write \makemacros{foo}{key1 = val1, key2 = val2}, and have it parsed as before, should be a needed feature for a good LaTeX command. Though, I don't seem to be able to wrap my head around how I should do it.
Every time I make an attempt in fixing this, I either make my compiler angry, raising a ridiculous amount of errors that won't compile anything, or just delete the whole content of my macros. In fact, I think that the problem is related to the fact that the compiler expects me to print the content of strange macros, which have actual space characters as part of their name; which, of course, is not at all what I'm intending, because I'd rather trim off the spaces in order to avoid messing with them afterwards.
Anyone that has a good idea on how to handle it? I think I should mention that I recently discovered that a command like \def\@trimstart#1{#1} actually works to trim every amount of spaces at the start of the argument... what's giving me headaches at the moment is the eventual spaces at the end of the argument itself. Maybe some tweaks to this command could work in the way I hope?

Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short TeX code you have tried so far? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

\@key1_foo{val1} - Having non-letters, e.g., digits, in macro-names usually is not a good idea as under usual catcode régime the tokenizer of TeX does not take non-letters for components of names of control word tokens.

"...as 2 different macros \@key1_foo{val1} and \@key2_foo{val2}." - What does this mean? Macros usually are denoted by control word tokens that are defined to be macros. Do you really wnt the name of the control word token to be @key1_foo{val1} resp @key2_foo{val2}? If this is not about macros but about macro-calls: What are the definitions of \@key1 and \@key2 to be? What is the math-subscript indicated by _ about? Do you really only want subsequent letter f from foo in subscript? Is \@key1_foo the control word token and val1 the undelimited/brace-nested argument?

It sounds as if you want to implement a keyval parsers: there are several already available, from the classical keyval to l3keys and expkv. Is there a reason you've not simply picked one of these to do the hard work?

The matters of removing trailing space tokens or leading space tokens from an (almost) arbitrary token sequence by means of sentinel tokens (which may not possibly occur in the argument whose spaces are to be trimmed) and delimited macro arguments  is elaborated in detail by Michael Downes, ‘Around the Bend #15, answers’, a
summary of internet discussion which took place under his guidance primarily at the INFO-TEX list, but also at comp.text.tex (usenet) and via private email; December 1993. Online archived at http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/challenges/AroBend/AroundTheBend.pdf.
With the routine \UD@TrimAllSurroundingSpaces{<Argument>}{<Tokens to prepend>} in the vintage-code-solution below another approach is implemented which does without forbidden sentinel tokens:
The argument whose surrounding space tokens are to be trimmed is taken for a list of space-token-delimited items. Space-token-delimited items are stripped from the remaining old list and accumulated one by one in the new list until the remaining old list is blank, i.e., is empty or consists only of space tokens. This way all trailing space tokens are removed no matter how many of them might be there in edge cases. All leading space tokens, no matter how many of them might be there in edge cases, are removed as while accumulating space-token-delimited arguments a space token is prepended to a space-token-delimited-argument in the new list only if the new list gathered so far is not empty. (When grabbing delimited arguments, it must be ensured that curly braces which surround an entire delimited argument do not get stripped off - that's what the \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces-thingie is about.)

Probably \keyval_parse:nnn from LaTeX 2e's L3 programming layer, documented in interface3.pdf, section Data Types, The l3keys module - Key-value interfaces, does what you need.
If you can neither have \keyval_parse:nnn nor have some other component of the l3keys-module do directly what you need, you can probably use \keyval_parse:nnn for normalizing your key=value-list, i.e., for removing spaces etc, before passing your key=value-list on to the macro which does the actual work with it:
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Nn \mystuff_keyval:n {\exp_not:n{#1},}
\cs_new:Nn \mystuff_keyval:nn {\exp_not:n{#1={#2}},}
\cs_new:Npn \normalizekv #1#2 {
  \exp_args:Nne 
    \use:n 
    {
      \exp_args:Nne 
        \use:n 
        {#1}
    }
    {\keyval_parse:nnn {\mystuff_keyval:n}{\mystuff_keyval:nn}{#2}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\makemacros[2]{%
  \message{^^J%
    Argument 1 is {\detokenize{#1}}^^J%
    Argument 2 is {\detokenize{#2}}^^J%
    ^^J%
  }%
}%

\normalizekv{\makemacros{foo}}{key1=val1,key2=val2,key3}

\normalizekv{\makemacros{foo}}{key1 = val1, key2 = val2 , key3 }

\stop

The example above comes along with a dummy-definition of \makemacro which just prints to console its first argument, i.e., the name of the key-family, and its second argument, i.e., the normalized key=value-list.
I get the following messages on the console:
$ pdflatex test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>

Argument 1 is {foo}
Argument 2 is {key1={val1},key2={val2},key3,}


Argument 1 is {foo}
Argument 2 is {key1={val1},key2={val2},key3,}

 )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.

With the two calls to \normalizekv the second arguments of \makemacros, i.e., the key=value-lists, look the same although only with the second call there are some spaces.

If you prefer vintage code, you can implement a \romannumeral-expansion-driven loop for iterating a comma-separated list, with each comma-delimited item removing surrounding space tokens both from the things before the first = and from the things after the first =. When grabbing delimited arguments, it must be ensured that curly braces which surround an entire delimited argument do not get stripped off - that's what the \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces-thingie is about.
Unlike the expl3-solution above, the vintage-code-solution below

relies on = and , having category 12(other).
does not remove blank items from the comma list but turns them into empty items.

Edit: With the vintage-code-solution it was overlooked that only space tokens surrounding keys / values should be removed while space tokens within keys / values should remain. This is now rectified.
%%\errorcontextlines=10000
\makeatletter
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Paraphernalia:
%%.............................................................................
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecondAndThird[3]{#2{#1}#3{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00 }%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Extract first inner delimited argument:
%%
%% With \long\def\UD@KeepToComma#1,{{\UD@firstoftwo#1}}
%%
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces{\UD@KeepToComma}{A,B,C,D,E}{<Tokens to prepend>} yields  <Tokens to prepend>{A}
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces{\UD@KeepToComma}{{AB},C,D,E}{<Tokens to prepend>} yields  <Tokens to prepend>{{AB}}
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces{\UD@KeepToComma}{AB,C,D,E}{<Tokens to prepend>} yields  <Tokens to prepend>{AB}
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces{\UD@KeepToComma}{ AB ,C,D,E}{<Tokens to prepend>} yields  <Tokens to prepend>{<space token>AB<space token>}
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces{\UD@KeepToComma}{AB ,C,D,E}{<Tokens to prepend>} yields  <Tokens to prepend>{AB<space token>}
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces{\UD@KeepToComma}{ AB,C,D,E}{<Tokens to prepend>} yields  <Tokens to prepend>{<space token>AB}
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces{\UD@KeepToComma}{{AB,AB},C,D,E}{<Tokens to prepend>} yields  <Tokens to prepend>{{AB,AB}}
%%
%% When you triggered \romannumeral-expansion, you can terminate
%% \romannumeral-expansion by having <Tokens to prepend> = \UD@stopromannumeral...
%%
%% \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces's argument must contain the delimiter
%% outside curly braces!!!!  This is not checked but needs to be checked by the
%% routine that might call \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces !
%%
%% Use frozen-\relax as delimiter for speeding things up.
%% Frozen-\relax was chosen because David Carlisle pointed out in
%% <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578877>
%% that frozen-\relax cannot be (re)defined in terms of \outer and cannot be
%% affected by \uppercase/\lowercase.
%%
%% \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces's argument may contain frozen-\relax:
%% The only effect is that internally more iterations are needed for
%% obtaining the result.
%%
%%.............................................................................
\@ifdefinable\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@Exchange
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\ifnum0=0\fi}%
  {\long\def\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax#1#2}{{#1}}%
}%
\expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter
  \UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\romannumeral
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@Exchange
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\ifnum0=0\fi}%
    {\UD@stopromannumeral\expandafter\expandafter#1{}{}#2{}}%
  }{%
    \UD@stopromannumeral
    \expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBracesLoop
    \expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter
  }%
}{%
  \newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces[2]%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBracesLoop[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  {\UD@Exchange{#1}}%
  {\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBracesLoop
   \expandafter{\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax#1}}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Remove all surrounding spaces from argument 
%%
%% \UD@TrimAllSurroundingSpaces{<Argument>}{<Tokens to prepend>}
%% yields <Tokens to prepend>{<Argument with all surrounding spaces removed>}
%%
%% When you triggered \romannumeral-expansion, you can terminate
%% \romannumeral-expansion by having <Tokens to prepend> = \UD@stopromannumeral...
%%.............................................................................
\@ifdefinable\UD@GobbleToSpace{\long\def\UD@GobbleToSpace#1 {}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@KeepToSpace{\long\def\UD@KeepToSpace#1 {{\UD@firstoftwo#1}}}%
\newcommand\UD@NoSurroundBraces[2]{#1#2}%
\newcommand\UD@TrimAllSurroundingSpaces[1]{%
  \UD@TrimAllSurroundingspacesLoop{#1 }{}{}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@TrimAllSurroundingspacesLoop[3]{%
  % #1 remaining list of space-delimited arguments
  % #2 Separator
  % #3 result gathered so far
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo#1{}{}}{%
    \UD@PassFirstToSecond{#3}%
  }{%
    \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecondAndThird\expandafter{%
      \romannumeral
      \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces{\UD@KeepToSpace}{#1}{\UD@NoSurroundBraces{\UD@stopromannumeral#3#2}}%
    }{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherNull
    }{%
      {\UD@PassFirstToSecond{}}{\UD@PassFirstToSecond{ }}%
      {\expandafter\UD@TrimAllSurroundingspacesLoop\expandafter{\UD@GobbleToSpace#1}}%
    }%
  }%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\@ifdefinable\UD@GobbleToComma{\long\def\UD@GobbleToComma#1,{}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@KeepToComma{\long\def\UD@KeepToComma#1,{{\UD@firstoftwo#1}}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@GobbleToEqual{\long\def\UD@GobbleToEqual#1={}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@KeepToEqual{\long\def\UD@KeepToEqual#1={{\UD@firstoftwo#1}}}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Split first argument at the first "=" and remove surrounding spaces and
%% prepend the second argument to the result - the second argument of
% \UD@SplitAtEqual is gathered via \UD@Exchange and can be used for terminating
% \romannumeral-driven expansion:
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\UD@SplitAtEqual[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@GobbleToEqual#1=}{%
    \UD@TrimAllSurroundingSpaces{#1}{\UD@Exchange}%
  }{%
    \expandafter\UD@Exchange\expandafter{%
      \romannumeral
      \expandafter\UD@TrimAllSurroundingSpaces\expandafter{\UD@GobbleToEqual#1}{\UD@Exchange}%
      {%
        \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces{\UD@KeepToEqual}{#1}{\UD@TrimAllSurroundingSpaces}{\UD@NoSurroundBraces{\UD@stopromannumeral}}=%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\normalizekv[2]{%
  \romannumeral\normalizekvloop{#2}{}{\UD@stopromannumeral#1}%
}%
\newcommand\normalizekvloop[2]{%
  % #1: remaining key=value-list to normalize
  % #2: key=value-list normalized so far
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@GobbleToComma#1,}{%
    \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\romannumeral\UD@SplitAtEqual{#1}{\UD@stopromannumeral#2}}%
  }{%
    \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{%
      \romannumeral
      \UD@ExtractFirstDelimitedArgKeepBraces{\UD@KeepToComma}{#1}{\UD@SplitAtEqual}{\UD@stopromannumeral#2},%
    }{%
      \expandafter\normalizekvloop\expandafter{\UD@GobbleToComma#1}%
    }%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\newcommand\makemacros[2]{%
  \message{^^J%
    Argument 1 is {\detokenize{#1}}^^J%
    Argument 2 is {\detokenize{#2}}^^J%
    ^^J%
  }%
}%

\normalizekv{\makemacros{foo}}{key1=val1,key2=val2,key3}

\normalizekv{\makemacros{foo}}{key1 = val1, key2 = val2 , key3 }

\normalizekv{\makemacros{foo}}{key1={val1},key2=val2,key3}

\normalizekv{\makemacros{foo}}{key1 = {val1}, key2 = val2 , key3 }

\normalizekv{\makemacros{foo}}{k e y 1=v a l 1,k e y 2=v a l 2,k e y 3}

\normalizekv{\makemacros{foo}}{k e y 1 = v a l 1, k e y 2 = v a l 2 , k e y 3 }

\normalizekv{\makemacros{foo}}{k e y 1={v a l 1},k e y 2=v a l 2,k e y 3}

\normalizekv{\makemacros{foo}}{k e y 1 = {v a l 1}, k e y 2 = v a l 2 , k e y 3 }

\normalizekv{\makemacros{foo}}{k e y 1={v a l 1},k e y 2=v a l 2,k e y 3,,}

\normalizekv{\makemacros{foo}}{k e y 1 = {v a l 1}, k e y 2 = v a l 2 , k e y 3 , , }

\stop

Console output:
$ pdflatex test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>

Argument 1 is {foo}
Argument 2 is {key1=val1,key2=val2,key3}


Argument 1 is {foo}
Argument 2 is {key1=val1,key2=val2,key3}


Argument 1 is {foo}
Argument 2 is {key1={val1},key2=val2,key3}


Argument 1 is {foo}
Argument 2 is {key1={val1},key2=val2,key3}



Argument 1 is {foo}
Argument 2 is {k e y 1=v a l 1,k e y 2=v a l 2,k e y 3}



Argument 1 is {foo}
Argument 2 is {k e y 1=v a l 1,k e y 2=v a l 2,k e y 3}



Argument 1 is {foo}
Argument 2 is {k e y 1={v a l 1},k e y 2=v a l 2,k e y 3}



Argument 1 is {foo}
Argument 2 is {k e y 1={v a l 1},k e y 2=v a l 2,k e y 3}



Argument 1 is {foo}
Argument 2 is {k e y 1={v a l 1},k e y 2=v a l 2,k e y 3,,}



Argument 1 is {foo}
Argument 2 is {k e y 1={v a l 1},k e y 2=v a l 2,k e y 3,,}

 )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.


For the vintage code one: Why not use expkv :P It's written in plain e-TeX.

@Skillmon I did not write an expkv example because I assumed the author of that package himself would like to write an answer sooner or later. ;-)

If we want to remove initial spaces and trailing spaces from a parameter of a macro at expand processor level using TeX primitives only, then we can do following:
\long\def\nospaces #1#2{\nospaceafter \macroA #2.\fin//#1}
\long\def\macroA #1\fin//{% initial spaces removed
   \macroB \empty#1\fin// .\fin//\raw\empty#1\fin//%
}
\long\def\macroB #1 .\fin//#2\raw#3.\fin//#4{%
   \ifx^#2^\expandafter#4\expandafter{#3}%
   \else\expandafter#4\expandafter{#1}\fi
}
\def\nospaceafter#1{\expandafter#1\romannumeral-`\.\noexpand} % borrowed from OpTeX

\long\def\macro #1{% for testing only
   \message{the parameter doesn't include initial+trailing spaces: "\detokenize{#1}"}%
}

%% tests
\nospaces \macro{ argu ment }
\nospaces \macro{next argument}
\nospaces \macro{\empty argument }
\nospaces \macro{ \empty next argument}
\nospaces \macro{}
\nospaces \macro{ {test}}
\nospaces \macro{{x}}
\nospaces \macro{{}}

\bye

In OpTeX key-value implementation, the spaces around = and ' are striped by the \replstring macro:
\def\normalizekv#1#2{\def\tmpb{#2,}%
   \replstring\tmpb{= }{=}\replstring\tmpb{ =}{=}%
   \replstring\tmpb{, }{,}\replstring\tmpb{ ,}{,}%
   \ea\normalizekvA\tmpb\_fin{#1}
}
\def\normalizekvA #1,\_fin #2{#2{#1}}

%% Testing:
\def\makemacros#1#2{\wterm{makemacros\detokenize{{#1}{#2}}}}

\normalizekv{\makemacros{foo}}{key1=val1,key2=val2,key3}
\normalizekv{\makemacros{foo}}{key1 = val1, key2 = val2 , key3 }
\normalizekv{\makemacros{foo}}{key1={val1},key2=val2,key3}
\normalizekv{\makemacros{foo}}{key1 = {val1}, key2 = val2 , key3 }
\normalizekv{\makemacros{foo}}{k e y 1=v a l 1,k e y 2=v a l 2,k e y 3}
\normalizekv{\makemacros{foo}}{k e y 1 = v a l 1, k e y 2 = v a l 2 , k e y 3 }
\normalizekv{\makemacros{foo}}{k e y 1={v a l 1},k e y 2=v a l 2,k e y 3}
\normalizekv{\makemacros{foo}}{k e y 1 = {v a l 1}, k e y 2 = v a l 2 , k e y 3 }
\normalizekv{\makemacros{foo}}{k e y 1={v a l 1},k e y 2=v a l 2,k e y 3,,}
\normalizekv{\makemacros{foo}}{k e y 1 = {v a l 1}, k e y 2 = v a l 2 , k e y 3 , , }

\bye

There is strength in simplicity.

This answer focuses on the aspect of trimming white space from an argument and forwarding the result to anything else (as there already exists an excellent answer tackling the more complex problem OP described). This is done so that people who stumble across the heading on later searches still find something useful.
In modern LaTeX there are a few different levels at which this problem can be tackled. The most abstract and most simple to use method to trim a single argument's outer most spaces is to use ltcmd and its \TrimSpaces processor:
\NewDocumentCommand \foo { >{\TrimSpaces} m }{\typeout{Argument was `#1'}}
\foo{ abc }

Another approach is readily available in the L3 layer (this is not a complete introduction into that syntax, if you need that search for help regarding expl3 syntax), which is \tl_trim_spaces:n (to be used in an e-type argument) or \tl_trim_spaces_apply:nN (as a forwarding function):
\cs_new:Nn \my_foo:n { \__my_foo:e { \tl_trim_spaces:n {#1} } }
\cs_new:Nn \my_Foo:n { \tl_trim_spaces_apply:nN {#1} \__my_foo:n }

\cs_new:Nn \__my_foo:n { \tl_show:n {#1} }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__my_foo:n { e }


As an educational exhibition let's take a look at how one can expandably shave off spaces. This here will describe the mechanism in plain TeX syntax (but with e-Tex) (the approach used in L3 and behind the scenes in ltcmd is basically the same -- though the code is not necessarily identical).
The basic idea is to use delimited arguments, that means macros that read their arguments up to a specific combination of tokens. For instance \def\foo#1\bar{} will read everything until it finds a token \bar (and then expand to nothing). This can also be used to eat spaces by making the combination of an internal token and a space the delimiting text. So something like \def\foo#1 \bar{} will take as its argument everything until it finds a \bar that was immediately preceded by a space. That piece of code can gobble spaces at the end of our argument (we just have to make sure to stop doing so after the last space was removed).
The problem is that this method will throw a low level TeX error if the delimiting tokens aren't found, which is why we always have to provide a fallback set of those. With that out of the way we also need to decide what to do next, after we removed the space if there was one, or if there was none. For that we use a second delimited argument, \def\foo#1 \bar#2\baz#3{#3{#1}} will read everything up to a space followed by \bar, then everything until the next \baz and expand to the token following that, which gets the first argument as its argument.
A last thing to consider is that whenever TeX reads a delimited argument, if the entire delimited argument is surrounded by braces those braces are removed, but if a single token (doesn't matter which token and whether at the before or after the braces) is outside the braces they aren't removed. In the following code during the removal of leading spaces the trailing \spacestripper@post is always part of the delimited argument, preventing accidental brace removal. Similarly during the removal of trailing spaces the \spacestripper@pre is always there protecting the braces. And during the final step in \spacestripper@d we grab everything up to \spacestripper@post (so we still have the leading pre) and clean up the remainder of our loops. Afterwards we need to remove the leading pre in a way that doesn't affect bracing, which we do using \expandafter while the pre-token has an empty replacement text.
With these building blocks we can build our space stripper:
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
% we use `\edef` so that we can introduce `\space`s in our replacement text.
% Note that we already placed both `pre<space>` and `<space>post` here, as well
% as a final delimiter `stop`.
\long\edef\spacestripper#1%
  {%
    \noexpand\spacestripper@a
      \noexpand\spacestripper@pre#1\noexpand\spacestripper@post
      \unexpanded{\spacestripper@mark\spacestripper@a}%
      \noexpand\spacestripper@pre\space\space\noexpand\spacestripper@post
      \unexpanded{\spacestripper@mark\spacestripper@b}%
      \noexpand\spacestripper@stop
  }
% If there is a space at the start of our argument remove it and pick up
% `\spacestripper@a` as #3, removing that single space and looping.
% If there is no space grab everything until the placed `pre<space>` in #1, and
% #3 will be `\spacestripper@b`.
\long\unexpanded{\def\spacestripper@a#1\spacestripper@pre} % <- space after pre
    #2\spacestripper@mark#3%
  {#3#1\spacestripper@pre#2\spacestripper@mark#3}
% clean up the remainder of the `\spacestripper@a` loop and insert
% `\spacestripper@c`.
\long\def\spacestripper@b
    #1\spacestripper@mark\spacestripper@a
    \spacestripper@pre#2\spacestripper@mark\spacestripper@b
  {%
    \spacestripper@c#1\spacestripper@mark\spacestripper@c
    #2\spacestripper@mark\spacestripper@d
  }
% If there is a space at the end of our argument remove it and pick up
% `\spacestripper@c` as #3, removing that single space and looping.
% If there is no space grab everything until the placed `<space>post` in #1, and
% #3 will be `\spacestripper@d`.
\long\def\spacestripper@c#1 \spacestripper@post#2\spacestripper@mark#3%
  {#3#1\spacestripper@post#2\spacestripper@mark#3}
% clean up the remainder of the `\spacestripper@c` loop (using the `stop` mark),
% and leave the result in the input stream.
\long\def\spacestripper@d#1\spacestripper@post#2\spacestripper@stop
  {\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}}
% expand to nothing, this way a single `\expandafter` is enough to get rid of
% the leading `pre`.
\def\spacestripper@pre{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
A\spacestripper{ abc }b.

% multiple spaces on either end
A\expanded{\noexpand\spacestripper{\UseName{@spaces} abc \UseName{@spaces}}}b.
\end{document}


You can use expl3 features regarding absorbing key-value pairs.
The \makemacros command stores the key-value pairs in a property list and the procedure trims off spaces around = and also around ,.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\makemacros}{mm}
 {% #1 = class, #2 = list of key-value pairs
  \prop_clear:N \l_tmpa_prop
  \prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_tmpa_prop {#2}
  \prop_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_prop
   {% ##1 is the key, ##2 is the value
    \cs_new:cpn {@##1@#1} {##2}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\makemacros{foo}{keyA=val1, keyB =val2, keyC = val3 }

\makeatletter

\show\@keyA@foo
\show\@keyB@foo
\show\@keyC@foo

\stop

You could use _ before the common postfix (which I name “class”), but then you need to properly set the category code of _ in order to call the built macros.
Running the above code yields
> \@keyA@foo=\long macro:
->val1.
l.21 \show\@keyA@foo

?
> \@keyB@foo=\long macro:
->val2.
l.22 \show\@keyB@foo

?
> \@keyC@foo=\long macro:
->val3.
l.23 \show\@keyC@foo

?

on the console.
